# How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I have a windows forms app with a textbox control that I want to only accept integer values. In the past I've done this kind of validation by overloading the KeyPress event and just removing characters which didn't fit the specification. I've looked at the MaskedTextBox control but I'd like a more general solution that could work with perhaps a regular expression, or depend on the values of other controls.

Ideally this would behave such that pressing a non numeric character would either produce no result or immediately provide the user with feedback about the invalid character.

Comment: numbers or digits?  big difference: even integers can go negative

Comment: The question was intended for numbers including the entire set of rational numbers.

Answer (score 931, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use a [`NumericUpDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. NumericUpDown does the filtering for you, which is nice. Of course it also gives your users the ability to hit the up and down arrows on the keyboard to increment and decrement the current value.
2. Handle the appropriate keyboard events to prevent anything but numeric input. I've had success with this two event handlers on a standard TextBox:

   ```
   private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
   {
       if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
           (e.KeyChar != '.'))
       {
               e.Handled = true;
       }

       // only allow one decimal point
       if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
       {
           e.Handled = true;
       }
   }
   ```

You can remove the check for `'.'` (and the subsequent check for more than one `'.'`) if your TextBox shouldn't allow decimal places. You could also add a check for `'-'` if your TextBox should allow negative values.

If you want to limit the user for number of digit, use: `textBox1.MaxLength = 2; // this will allow the user to enter only 2 digits`

Comment: I'd forgotten the numeric up down control exists. It's actually what I should be using here instead of a textbox. In the future when I have more complicated validation I'll used the handled property with the KeyPress event.

Comment: The only drawback with NumericUpDown is that it provides no feedback when you enter a value outside of the Maximum or Minimum allowed values - it just changes what you've typed. A TextBox can at least allow invalid values so you can warn the user when they submit the form.

Comment: It is also possible to get values into a textbox with just the mouse

Comment: That's true - the user could always paste in some non-numeric characters. You would hope that the form validation would catch that though, since at some point you're gonna want to do an Int32.TryParse or something.

Comment: You'll need some addition effort to globalize this by replacing checks for '.' with checks on CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator.

Comment: @Matt, why do you care about the Control key? `if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)`

Comment: @Hamish if the user is hitting Ctrl+3, I know I don't need to continue.

Comment: @HamishGrubijan, IsControl has nothing to do with the Control key; it returns whether or not a char is a control char. By allowing control chars, you don't break things like backspace, delete or the arrow keys

Comment: Is it `TextChanged()` now instead of `KeyPress()`?

Comment: This is useful as an extension too.

Comment: This still accepts illegal ctrl+v input, by the way; a bug which even exists in the official NumericUpDown control.

Comment: Seems like this code accepts 123-456 as a valid input. We should also consider the index at which - is placed

Comment: may be we can change code 
From : 

 // only allow one decimal point
   ` if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

to  : 
 // only allow one decimal point only in the beginning
            if (e.KeyChar == '-')
            {
                if ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('-') > -1)
                    return true;
                if ((sender as TextBox).Text.Length > 0)
                    return true;
            }`

Comment: You can set numericUpDown ReadOnly. Then you can only increment/decrement with arrows. Paste will not work

Comment: Just keep in mind that the numericUpDown.Value is decimal and has a different range than float or double (±1.5 x E−45 to ±3.4 x E38 and ±5.0 × E−324 to ±1.7 × E308, respectively) compared to that of decimal type (±1.0 x E-28 to ±7.9228 x E28).  So, if you need very large or very small numbers, numericUpDown may not be suitable.

Comment: works, but there's an error when I paste something with control + v, letters are still added.

Comment: @EduardoHerrera you can use `onChange` event i guess to prevent `ctrl+v` by clearing the entire text or do whatever. Though I think numericUpDown is kinda ugly if you need to accept some big numbers.

Answer (score 188):

And just because it's always more fun to do stuff in one line...

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
    }
```

NOTE: This DOES NOT prevent a user from Copy / Paste into this textbox. It's not a fail safe way to sanitize your data.

Comment: this is not a general solutions as it works only for intergers. I had to implement such thing recently and i ended up with try-parsing resulting string to number and allowing input only if parsing succeeded

Comment: This may not work when multiple methods handle `KeyPress` events from the same text box. One event might set `e.Handled` to true, and then another could set it back to false. In general, it's better to use `if (...) e.Handled = true;`

Comment: You can disable ShortcutsEnabled property to prevent copy paste by keyboard or menu

Comment: Eh. A `TextChanged` event that goes over it with a regex can fix copy-paste ;)

Comment: 1st: The one liner CAN prevent copy/paste if you fix the bug in it (`&& !` must be a `||`). 2nd: You can fix it, so that it prevents only paste and yet allows copy/cut/select all.

Comment: for the paste issue, I just overrided the `WndProc` method, and ignore it (paste code = 0x0302) if it contains non digits: string text = Text;
                PasteEventArgs e = new PasteEventArgs(text, Clipboard.GetText(), SelectionStart, SelectionLength);
                TextPasted(this, e);
                if (!e.Handled && text.Equals(Text))
                    Text = text.Substring(0, e.SelectionStart) + e.PastedText + text.Substring(e.SelectionStart + e.SelectionLength);

Answer (score 60):

I am assuming from context and the tags you used that you are writing a .NET C# app. In this case, you can subscribe to the text changed event, and validate each key stroke.

```cs
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "[^0-9]"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that going to give a very weird effect if you type into the middle of a number?

Comment: and also it should be:
`textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);`

Comment: what if the first character itself is not a digit...wouldn't subtracting 1 in that case throw an error....

Comment: Also, using TextChanged instead of KeyPress creates a bit of recursion in that the code will jump into a second TextChanged event after the Remove method.

Comment: You switched input and pattern parameters for your IsMatch function. Input should be first, then pattern.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The remove will remove all the text rather than the invalid char. I think it will be better to store the previous valid change and update accordingly.

Comment: resolve the problem with TextChangedEventArgs and use e.Changes -> Change.Offset

Answer (score 40):

Here is a simple standalone Winforms custom control, derived from the standard TextBox, that allows only System.Int32 input (it could be easily adapted for other types such as System.Int64, etc.). It supports copy/paste operations and negative numbers:

```
public class Int32TextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);

        NumberFormatInfo fi = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;

        string c = e.KeyChar.ToString();
        if (char.IsDigit(c, 0))
            return;

        if ((SelectionStart == 0) && (c.Equals(fi.NegativeSign)))
            return;

        // copy/paste
        if ((((int)e.KeyChar == 22) || ((int)e.KeyChar == 3))
            && ((ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control))
            return;

        if (e.KeyChar == '\b')
            return;

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;
        if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
        {
            string text = Clipboard.GetText();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                return;

            if ((text.IndexOf('+') >= 0) && (SelectionStart != 0))
                return;

            int i;
            if (!int.TryParse(text, out i)) // change this for other integer types
                return;

            if ((i < 0) && (SelectionStart != 0))
                return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

**Update 2017**: My first answer has some issues:

- you can type something that's longer than an integer of a given type (for example 2147483648 is greater than Int32.MaxValue);
- more generally, there's no real validation of the *result* of what has been typed;
- it only handles int32, you'll have to write specific TextBox derivated control for each type (Int64, etc.)

So I came up with another version that's more generic, that still supports copy/paste, + and - sign, etc.

```
public class ValidatingTextBox : TextBox
{
    private string _validText;
    private int _selectionStart;
    private int _selectionEnd;
    private bool _dontProcessMessages;

    public event EventHandler<TextValidatingEventArgs> TextValidating;

    protected virtual void OnTextValidating(object sender, TextValidatingEventArgs e) => TextValidating?.Invoke(sender, e);

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (_dontProcessMessages)
            return;

        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_ENTERIDLE = 0x121;
        const int VK_DELETE = 0x2e;

        bool delete = m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN && (int)m.WParam == VK_DELETE;
        if ((m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN && !delete) || m.Msg == WM_ENTERIDLE)
        {
            DontProcessMessage(() =>
            {
                _validText = Text;
                _selectionStart = SelectionStart;
                _selectionEnd = SelectionLength;
            });
        }

        const int WM_CHAR = 0x102;
        const int WM_PASTE = 0x302;
        if (m.Msg == WM_CHAR || m.Msg == WM_PASTE || delete)
        {
            string newText = null;
            DontProcessMessage(() =>
            {
                newText = Text;
            });

            var e = new TextValidatingEventArgs(newText);
            OnTextValidating(this, e);
            if (e.Cancel)
            {
                DontProcessMessage(() =>
                {
                    Text = _validText;
                    SelectionStart = _selectionStart;
                    SelectionLength = _selectionEnd;
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private void DontProcessMessage(Action action)
    {
        _dontProcessMessages = true;
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        finally
        {
            _dontProcessMessages = false;
        }
    }
}

public class TextValidatingEventArgs : CancelEventArgs
{
    public TextValidatingEventArgs(string newText) => NewText = newText;
    public string NewText { get; }
}
```

For Int32, you can either derive from it, like this:

```
public class Int32TextBox : ValidatingTextBox
{
    protected override void OnTextValidating(object sender, TextValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = !int.TryParse(e.NewText, out int i);
    }
}
```

or w/o derivation, use the new TextValidating event like this:

```
var vtb = new ValidatingTextBox();
...
vtb.TextValidating += (sender, e) => e.Cancel = !int.TryParse(e.NewText, out int i);
```

but what's nice is it works with any string, and any validation routine.

Comment: This is great, nice and simple, easily used, and deals with unusual input attempts. Thanks!

Comment: Note on the 2017 version, when there is one value e.g. 1 and you hit backspace it's ignored while if you had say 120 and hit backspace three times we are left with 1.

Comment: Your ValidatingTextbox is by far on of the best implementation I've seen for a while. Simple and effective. Thanks!

Comment: How can I implement it in my project 2019?

Comment: Could you make this work for TextBox with multiline true? I want to allow positive doubles on multiple lines

Comment: @SteveW - just update the `OnTextValidating` method the way you like, eg: `e.Cancel = !int.TryParse(e.NewText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty), out int i);` should support multiline

Comment: I can see how that code will work for int (as you seem to be concatenating the ints into a single int) but not for double due to multiple fullstops/periods?

Comment: @SteveW - depending on how you want to do it, you'll have to write some code to do validation yes.

Answer (score 28):

This is exactly what the Validated/Validating events were designed for.

Here's the MSDN article on the topic:
[Control.Validating Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx).

The TL;DR version: Check the `.Text` property in the `Validating` event and set `e.Cancel=True` when the data is invalid.

When you set `e.Cancel = True`, the user can't leave the field, but you will need to give them some kind of feedback that something's wrong. I change the box's background color to light red to indicate a problem. Make sure to set it back to `SystemColors.Window` when `Validating` is called with a good value.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a very API-idiomatic approach. I'm relatively new to Windows Forms, and it's quite a jungle of functionality & MSDN docs, so also thanks for the specific doc pointer to `Validating`. `<nitpick>`The OP mentions that immediately disallowing/indicating an invalidating character is ideal, but `Validating` seems to require that focus be moved to another form/control before it takes effect.`</nitpick>` Still, this is a great approach and always worth considering in the more general case.

Comment: This is a great solution as minimal implementation is required.  It is worth noting that the Validating event only occurs when the control loses focus.  However, it is easy enough to call the same validation function from keypress to get live validation.

Answer (score 14):

Try a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx). It takes a simple mask format so you can limit the input to numbers or dates or whatever.

Comment: I specifically do not want to use a MaskedTextBox. The formats they allow can be very limiting. They work for this case but I'd like to do something more general.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `TextChanged` event

```
private void textBox_BiggerThan_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    long a;
    if (! long.TryParse(textBox_BiggerThan.Text, out a))
    {
        // If not int clear textbox text or Undo() last operation
        textBox_LessThan.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it should work well if you used `Undo()`, but it results in an `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: It looks like the TextChanged propery is part of routine that you wanna undo(). I have variable for the whole window and I am using `public int txtBoxValue`, and if tryParse doesn't work, I revert text in txtBox by `txtBox.Text = txtBoxValue.ToString();`

Answer (score 9):

Just use a `NumericUpDown` control and set those ugly up down buttons visibility to `false`.

```
numericUpDown1.Controls[0].Visible = false;
```

`NumericUpDown` is actually a collection of controls containing a 'spin box' (up down buttons), a text box and some code to validate and wange-jangle it all together.

Marking:

```
YourNumericUpDown.Controls[0].visible = false
```

will hide the buttons while keeping the underlying code active.

While not being an obvious solution it is simple and effective. `.Controls[1]` would hide the text box portion if you wanted to do that instead.

Comment: The accepted answer did not include any information on how to remove the up down buttons, how to do so is not obvious as there are no human readable interfaces to enable or disable them.  NumericUpDown is actually a collection of controls containing a text box and a "spin box" (up down buttons) and some code handling input validation.

Answer (score 8):

This might be useful. It allows "real" numeric values, including proper decimal points and preceding plus or minus signs. Call it from within the related KeyPress event.

```
       private bool IsOKForDecimalTextBox(char theCharacter, TextBox theTextBox)
    {
        // Only allow control characters, digits, plus and minus signs.
        // Only allow ONE plus sign.
        // Only allow ONE minus sign.
        // Only allow the plus or minus sign as the FIRST character.
        // Only allow ONE decimal point.
        // Do NOT allow decimal point or digits BEFORE any plus or minus sign.

        if (
            !char.IsControl(theCharacter)
            && !char.IsDigit(theCharacter)
            && (theCharacter != '.')
            && (theCharacter != '-')
            && (theCharacter != '+')
        )
        {
            // Then it is NOT a character we want allowed in the text box.
            return false;
        }



        // Only allow one decimal point.
        if (theCharacter == '.'
            && theTextBox.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            // Then there is already a decimal point in the text box.
            return false;
        }

        // Only allow one minus sign.
        if (theCharacter == '-'
            && theTextBox.Text.IndexOf('-') > -1)
        {
            // Then there is already a minus sign in the text box.
            return false;
        }

        // Only allow one plus sign.
        if (theCharacter == '+'
            && theTextBox.Text.IndexOf('+') > -1)
        {
            // Then there is already a plus sign in the text box.
            return false;
        }

        // Only allow one plus sign OR minus sign, but not both.
        if (
            (
                (theCharacter == '-')
                || (theCharacter == '+')
            )
            && 
            (
                (theTextBox.Text.IndexOf('-') > -1)
                ||
                (theTextBox.Text.IndexOf('+') > -1)
            )
            )
        {
            // Then the user is trying to enter a plus or minus sign and
            // there is ALREADY a plus or minus sign in the text box.
            return false;
        }

        // Only allow a minus or plus sign at the first character position.
        if (
            (
                (theCharacter == '-')
                || (theCharacter == '+')
            )
            && theTextBox.SelectionStart != 0
            )
        {
            // Then the user is trying to enter a minus or plus sign at some position 
            // OTHER than the first character position in the text box.
            return false;
        }

        // Only allow digits and decimal point AFTER any existing plus or minus sign
        if  (
                (
                    // Is digit or decimal point
                    char.IsDigit(theCharacter)
                    ||
                    (theCharacter == '.')
                )
                &&
                (
                    // A plus or minus sign EXISTS
                    (theTextBox.Text.IndexOf('-') > -1)
                    ||
                    (theTextBox.Text.IndexOf('+') > -1)
                )
                &&
                    // Attempting to put the character at the beginning of the field.
                    theTextBox.SelectionStart == 0
            )
        {
            // Then the user is trying to enter a digit or decimal point in front of a minus or plus sign.
            return false;
        }

        // Otherwise the character is perfectly fine for a decimal value and the character
        // may indeed be placed at the current insertion position.
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I've been working on a collection of components to complete missing stuff in WinForms, here it is: [Advanced Forms](https://bitbucket.org/bruce965/advanced-forms)

In particular this is the class for a Regex TextBox

```
/// <summary>Represents a Windows text box control that only allows input that matches a regular expression.</summary>
public class RegexTextBox : TextBox
{
    [NonSerialized]
    string lastText;

    /// <summary>A regular expression governing the input allowed in this text field.</summary>
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public virtual Regex Regex { get; set; }

    /// <summary>A regular expression governing the input allowed in this text field.</summary>
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [Category("Behavior")]
    [Description("Sets the regular expression governing the input allowed for this control.")]
    public virtual string RegexString {
        get {
            return Regex == null ? string.Empty : Regex.ToString();
        }
        set {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                Regex = null;
            else
                Regex = new Regex(value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) {
        if (Regex != null && !Regex.IsMatch(Text)) {
            int pos = SelectionStart - Text.Length + (lastText ?? string.Empty).Length;
            Text = lastText;
            SelectionStart = Math.Max(0, pos);
        }

        lastText = Text;

        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Simply adding something like `myNumbericTextBox.RegexString = "^(\\d+|)$";` should suffice.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use this code in the `TextBox`:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    double parsedValue;
    if (!double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out parsedValue))
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Both integers and floats need to be accepted, including the negative numbers.

```c#
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Text
    string text = ((Control) sender).Text;

    // Is Negative Number?
    if (e.KeyChar == '-' && text.Length == 0)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
        return;
    }

    // Is Float Number?
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' && text.Length > 0 && !text.Contains("."))
    {
        e.Handled = false;
        return;
    }

    // Is Digit?
    e.Handled = (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have made something for this on [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/WinFormNumberBox).

It works by intercepting the TextChanged event. If the result is a good number it will be stored. If it is something wrong, the last good value will be restored. The source is a bit too large to publish here, but [here is a link to the class](http://www.codeplex.com/WinFormNumberBox/SourceControl/changeset/view/18543#282049) that handles the core of this logic.

Answer (score 4):

In our webpage with the definition of textbox we can add an `onkeypress` event for accepting only numbers. It will not show any message but it will prevent you from wrong input. It worked for me, user could not enter anything except number.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFrom"
     onkeypress="if(isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) return false;">
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my aproach:

1. using linq (easy to modify filter)
2. copy/paste proof code
3. keeps caret position when you press a forbidden character
4. accepts left zeroes
5. and any size numbers

   ```
   private void numeroCuenta_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string org = numeroCuenta.Text;
       string formated = string.Concat(org.Where(c => (c >= '0' && c <= '9')));
       if (formated != org)
       {
           int s = numeroCuenta.SelectionStart;
           if (s > 0 && formated.Length > s && org[s - 1] != formated[s - 1]) s--;
           numeroCuenta.Text = formated;
           numeroCuenta.SelectionStart = s;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice and short way to do it with .NET 5/Core

```cs
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyData != Keys.Back)
    e.SuppressKeyPress = !int.TryParse(Convert.ToString((char) e.KeyData), out int _);
}
```

Edit: Added support for backspace key

Comment: I'm looking for a way to allow positive ints/doubles in a multiline TextBox. Can your method do this?

Answer (score 2):

you could use [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx)/ Keypress event, use a regex to filter on numbers and take some action.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Input handling in WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294611/input-handling-in-winform)

I have posted my solution which uses the ProcessCmdKey and OnKeyPress events on the textbox. The comments show you how to use a Regex to verify the keypress and block/allow appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

I would handle it in the `KeyDown` event.

```
void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    char c = Convert.ToChar(e.PlatformKeyCode);
    if (!char.IsDigit(c))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about Keys like "Backspace", "Delete", "Arrow-Key-Left", "Arrow-Key-Right", Copy and Paste, Digits entered by Numpad (they are traded as !digit)

Comment: Just add a few more tests like this:  
        
            if (!char.IsDigit(c) && c != (char)Keys.Back)

Answer (score 2):

```
private void txt3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    for (int h = 58; h <= 127; h++)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == h)             //58 to 127 is alphabets tat will be         blocked
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    for(int k=32;k<=47;k++)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == k)              //32 to 47 are special characters tat will 
        {                                  be blocked
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

try this is very simple

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can do something like this in the textchanged event of the textbox.

here is a demo

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string actualdata = string.Empty;
        char[] entereddata = textBox1.Text.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char aChar in entereddata.AsEnumerable())
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(aChar))
            {
                actualdata = actualdata + aChar;
                // MessageBox.Show(aChar.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(aChar + " is not numeric");
                actualdata.Replace(aChar, ' ');
                actualdata.Trim();
            }
        }
        textBox1.Text = actualdata;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , its very useful.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like many of the current answers to this question are manually parsing the input text. If you're looking for a specific built-in numeric type (e.g. `int` or `double`), why not just delegate the work to that type's `TryParse` method? For example:

```
public class IntTextBox : TextBox
{
    string PreviousText = "";
    int BackingResult;

    public IntTextBox()
    {
        TextChanged += IntTextBox_TextChanged;
    }

    public bool HasResult { get; private set; }

    public int Result
    {
        get
        {
            return HasResult ? BackingResult : default(int);
        }
    }

    void IntTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HasResult = int.TryParse(Text, out BackingResult);

        if (HasResult || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
        {
            // Commit
            PreviousText = Text;
        }
        else
        {
            // Revert
            var changeOffset = Text.Length - PreviousText.Length;
            var previousSelectionStart =
                Math.Max(0, SelectionStart - changeOffset);

            Text = PreviousText;
            SelectionStart = previousSelectionStart;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want something more generic but still compatible with Visual Studio's Designer:

```
public class ParsableTextBox : TextBox
{
    TryParser BackingTryParse;
    string PreviousText = "";
    object BackingResult;

    public ParsableTextBox()
        : this(null)
    {
    }

    public ParsableTextBox(TryParser tryParse)
    {
        TryParse = tryParse;

        TextChanged += ParsableTextBox_TextChanged;
    }

    public delegate bool TryParser(string text, out object result);

    public TryParser TryParse
    {
        set
        {
            Enabled = !(ReadOnly = value == null);

            BackingTryParse = value;
        }
    }

    public bool HasResult { get; private set; }

    public object Result
    {
        get
        {
            return GetResult<object>();
        }
    }

    public T GetResult<T>()
    {
        return HasResult ? (T)BackingResult : default(T);
    }

    void ParsableTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BackingTryParse != null)
        {
            HasResult = BackingTryParse(Text, out BackingResult);
        }

        if (HasResult || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
        {
            // Commit
            PreviousText = Text;
        }
        else
        {
            // Revert
            var changeOffset = Text.Length - PreviousText.Length;
            var previousSelectionStart =
                Math.Max(0, SelectionStart - changeOffset);

            Text = PreviousText;
            SelectionStart = previousSelectionStart;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, if you want something fully generic and don't care about Designer support:

```
public class ParsableTextBox<T> : TextBox
{
    TryParser BackingTryParse;
    string PreviousText;
    T BackingResult;

    public ParsableTextBox()
        : this(null)
    {
    }

    public ParsableTextBox(TryParser tryParse)
    {
        TryParse = tryParse;

        TextChanged += ParsableTextBox_TextChanged;
    }

    public delegate bool TryParser(string text, out T result);

    public TryParser TryParse
    {
        set
        {
            Enabled = !(ReadOnly = value == null);

            BackingTryParse = value;
        }
    }

    public bool HasResult { get; private set; }

    public T Result
    {
        get
        {
            return HasResult ? BackingResult : default(T);
        }
    }

    void ParsableTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BackingTryParse != null)
        {
            HasResult = BackingTryParse(Text, out BackingResult);
        }

        if (HasResult || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
        {
            // Commit
            PreviousText = Text;
        }
        else
        {
            // Revert
            var changeOffset = Text.Length - PreviousText.Length;
            var previousSelectionStart =
                Math.Max(0, SelectionStart - changeOffset);

            Text = PreviousText;
            SelectionStart = previousSelectionStart;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the approach described in [Fabio Iotti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28702150) I have created a more generic solution:

```
public abstract class ValidatedTextBox : TextBox {
    private string m_lastText = string.Empty;
    protected abstract bool IsValid(string text);
    protected sealed override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsValid(Text)) {
            var pos = SelectionStart - Text.Length + m_lastText.Length;
            Text = m_lastText;
            SelectionStart = Math.Max(0, pos);
        }
        m_lastText = Text;
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
}
```

"ValidatedTextBox", which contains all nontrivial validation behavior.
All that's left to do is inherit from this class and override "IsValid" method with whatever validation logic is required.
For example, using this class, it is possible to create "RegexedTextBox" which will accept only strings which match specific regular expression:

```
public abstract class RegexedTextBox : ValidatedTextBox {
    private readonly Regex m_regex;
    protected RegexedTextBox(string regExpString) {
        m_regex = new Regex(regExpString);
    }
    protected override bool IsValid(string text) {
        return m_regex.IsMatch(Text);
    }
}
```

After that, inheriting from the "RegexedTextBox" class, we can easily create "PositiveNumberTextBox" and "PositiveFloatingPointNumberTextBox" controls:

```
public sealed class PositiveNumberTextBox : RegexedTextBox {
    public PositiveNumberTextBox() : base(@"^\d*$") { }
}

public sealed class PositiveFloatingPointNumberTextBox : RegexedTextBox {
    public PositiveFloatingPointNumberTextBox()
        : base(@"^(\d+\" + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + @")?\d*$") { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to wake the dead, but I thought someone might find this useful for future reference.

Here is how I handle it.  It handles floating point numbers, but can easily be modified for integers.

Basically you can only press **0** - **9** and **.**

You can only have one **0** before the **.**

All other characters are ignored and the cursor position maintained.

```
    private bool _myTextBoxChanging = false;

    private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        validateText(myTextBox);
    }

    private void validateText(TextBox box)
    {
        // stop multiple changes;
        if (_myTextBoxChanging)
            return;
        _myTextBoxChanging = true;

        string text = box.Text;
        if (text == "")
            return;
        string validText = "";
        bool hasPeriod = false;
        int pos = box.SelectionStart;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++ )
        {
            bool badChar = false;
            char s = text[i];
            if (s == '.')
            {
                if (hasPeriod)
                    badChar = true;
                else
                    hasPeriod = true;
            }
            else if (s < '0' || s > '9')
                badChar = true;

            if (!badChar)
                validText += s;
            else
            {
                if (i <= pos)
                    pos--;
            }
        }

        // trim starting 00s
        while (validText.Length >= 2 && validText[0] == '0')
        {
            if (validText[1] != '.')
            {
                validText = validText.Substring(1);
                if (pos < 2)
                    pos--;
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        if (pos > validText.Length)
            pos = validText.Length;
        box.Text = validText;
        box.SelectionStart = pos;
        _myTextBoxChanging = false;
    }
```

Here is a quickly modified int version:

```
    private void validateText(TextBox box)
    {
        // stop multiple changes;
        if (_myTextBoxChanging)
            return;
        _myTextBoxChanging = true;

        string text = box.Text;
        if (text == "")
            return;
        string validText = "";
        int pos = box.SelectionStart;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++ )
        {
            char s = text[i];
            if (s < '0' || s > '9')
            {
                if (i <= pos)
                    pos--;
            }
            else
                validText += s;
        }

        // trim starting 00s 
        while (validText.Length >= 2 && validText.StartsWith("00")) 
        { 
            validText = validText.Substring(1); 
            if (pos < 2) 
                pos--; 
        } 

        if (pos > validText.Length)
            pos = validText.Length;
        box.Text = validText;
        box.SelectionStart = pos;
        _myTextBoxChanging = false;
    }
```

Comment: This solution is reinventing the wheel with caveats. Localization for example.

Comment: How would you do this with multi-lines allowed?

Answer (score 1):

This one works with copy and paste, drag and drop, key down, prevents overflow and is pretty simple

```
public partial class IntegerBox : TextBox 
{
    public IntegerBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = 0.ToString();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }

    private String originalValue = 0.ToString();

    private void Integerbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        originalValue = this.Text;
    }

    private void Integerbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Text))
            {
                this.Text = 0.ToString();
            }
            this.Text = Convert.ToInt64(this.Text.Trim()).ToString();
        }
        catch (System.OverflowException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Value entered is to large max value: " + Int64.MaxValue.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.Text = originalValue;
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {                
            this.Text = originalValue;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            this.Text = originalValue;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK , MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for the best way to check only numbers in textbox and problem with keypress was it does not support copy paste by right click or clipboard so came up with  this code which validates the when cursor leaves the text field and also it checks for empty field. (adapted version of newguy)

```
private void txtFirstValue_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num;
    bool isNum = int.TryParse(txtFirstValue.Text.Trim(), out num);

    if (!isNum && txtFirstValue.Text != String.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The First Value You Entered Is Not a Number, Please Try Again", "Invalid Value Detected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        txtFirstValue.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: MouseLeave seems like a really bad choice for an event to use.

Comment: @LarsTech what I thought was textchanged even can causes error messagebox before even if user realizes error and try to fix it so I thought I would work better. What do you think is the best event for this case ?

Comment: @AlstonAntony late comment, i know. But a simple click event that activates on rightclick would suffice wouldnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget that a user can paste an invalid text in a `TextBox`.

If you want to restrict that, follow the below code:

```
private void ultraTextEditor1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string append="";
    foreach (char c in ultraTextEditor1.Text)
    {
        if ((!Char.IsNumber(c)) && (c != Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back)))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            append += c;
        }
    }

    ultraTextEditor1.Text = append;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are more than 30 answers and a lot of answers are helpful. But I want to share a generalized form for the **System.Windows.Forms.TextBox** and **System.Windows.Controls.TextBox**.

There is not available ***KeyPress*** event in **System.Windows.Controls.TextBox**.
This answer is for those people who want to implement with the same logic for **System.Windows.Forms.TextBox** and **System.Windows.Controls.TextBox**.

This is *NumberTextBox* code. Use commented line instead of the previous line for **System.Windows.Controls.TextBox**.

```
public class NumberTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
//public class NumberTextBox : System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
{
    private double _maxValue;
    private double _minValue;
    private bool _flag;
    private string _previousValue;

    public NumberTextBox()
    {
        this.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        //TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
        KeyDown += TextBox_KeyDown;
        TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        _minValue = double.MinValue;
        _maxValue = double.MaxValue;
    }

    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _previousValue = this.Text;
        _flag = this.SelectedText.Length > 0;
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var text = this.Text;
        if (text.Length < 1) return;
        var cursorPosition = SelectionStart == 0 ? SelectionStart : SelectionStart - 1;
        var insertedChar = text[cursorPosition];
        if (IsInvalidInput(insertedChar, cursorPosition, text))
        {
            HandleText(text, cursorPosition);
        }
        ValidateRange(text, cursorPosition);
    }

    private bool IsInvalidInput(char insertedChar, int cursorPosition, string text)
    {
        return !char.IsDigit(insertedChar) && insertedChar != '.' && insertedChar != '-' ||
               insertedChar == '-' && cursorPosition != 0 ||
               text.Count(x => x == '.') > 1 ||
               text.Count(x => x == '-') > 1;
    }

    private void HandleText(string text, int cursorPosition)
    {
        this.Text = _flag ? _previousValue : text.Remove(cursorPosition, 1);
        this.SelectionStart = cursorPosition;
        this.SelectionLength = 0;
    }

    private void ValidateRange(string text, int cursorPosition)
    {
        try
        {
            if (text == "." || _minValue < 0 && text == "-") return;
            var doubleValue = Convert.ToDouble(text);
            if (doubleValue > _maxValue || doubleValue < _minValue)
            {
                HandleText(text, cursorPosition);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            HandleText(text, cursorPosition);
        }
    }

    protected void SetProperties(double minValue = double.MinValue, double maxValue = double.MaxValue)
    {
        _minValue = minValue;
        _maxValue = maxValue;
    }       

}
```

*PositiveNumberTextBox* code:

```c#
public class PositiveNumberTextBox : NumberTextBox
{
    public PositiveNumberTextBox()
    {
        SetProperties(0);
    }
}
```

*FractionNumberTextBox* code:

```c#
public class FractionNumberTextBox : NumberTextBox
{
    public FractionNumberTextBox()
    {
        SetProperties(0, 0.999999);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this work for a multiline textbox? I want to allow the user to enter positive doubles on multiple lines

Comment: @SteveW, it doesn't work for multiline text. But you can Handle text after merging multiline values.

Answer (score 1):

one line code decimal point allowed

```
    private void txtQty_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled =  e.KeyChar != '.' && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
    }
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer. @John Garcia .

Comment: This won't work if a number is pasted into the textbox (from clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

```
int Number;
bool isNumber;
isNumber = int32.TryPase(textbox1.text, out Number);

if (!isNumber)
{ 
    (code if not an integer);
}
else
{
    (code if an integer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

3 solution

1)

```
//Add to the textbox's KeyPress event
//using Regex for number only textBox

private void txtBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "\\d+"))
e.Handled = true;
}
```

2)
an another solution from msdn

```
// Boolean flag used to determine when a character other than a number is entered.
private bool nonNumberEntered = false;
// Handle the KeyDown event to determine the type of character entered into the     control.
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
// Initialize the flag to false.
nonNumberEntered = false;
// Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the top of the keyboard.
if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
{
    // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the keypad.
    if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9)
    {
        // Determine whether the keystroke is a backspace.
        if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
        {
            // A non-numerical keystroke was pressed.
            // Set the flag to true and evaluate in KeyPress event.
            nonNumberEntered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (nonNumberEntered == true)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Please enter number only..."); 
       e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

source  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=VS.90).aspx

3)  using the MaskedTextBox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx

Comment: Please, edit solution 2... You left a "}" outside the code block

Answer (score 0):

In button click you can check text of textbox by for loop:

```
char[] c = txtGetCustomerId.Text.ToCharArray();
bool IsDigi = true;

for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
     {
       if (c[i] < '0' || c[i] > '9')
      { IsDigi = false; }
     }
 if (IsDigi)
    { 
     // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler answer:

```
_textBox.TextChanged += delegate(System.Object o, System.EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox _tbox = o as TextBox;
    _tbox.Text = new string(_tbox.Text.Where(c => (char.IsDigit(c)) || (c == '.')).ToArray());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**FAIL-SAFE** and simple "recursive" method, which can be used with multiple textboxes.

It blocks the wrong keyboard typed characters and also pasted values etc. It only accepts integer numbers, and **the maximum number length is the maximum length of a string type** (which is int, really long!)

```
public void Check_If_Int_On_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // This method checks that each inputed character is a number. Any non-numeric
   // characters are removed from the text

   TextBox textbox = (TextBox)sender;

   // If the text is empty, return
   if (textbox.Text.Length == 0) { return; }

   // Check the new Text value if it's only numbers
   byte parsedValue;
   if (!byte.TryParse(textbox.Text[(textbox.Text.Length - 1)].ToString(), out parsedValue))
   {
      // Remove the last character as it wasn't a number
      textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Remove((textbox.Text.Length - 1));

      // Move the cursor to the end of text
      textbox.SelectionStart = textbox.Text.Length;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i like terse code

```
    private void xmm_textbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        double x;
        e.Handled = !double.TryParse(((TextBox)sender).Text, out x);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a simple solution that works for me.

public static bool numResult;
    public static bool checkTextisNumber(string numberVal)
    {
        try
        {
            if (numberVal.Equals("."))
            {
                numResult = true;
            }
            else if (numberVal.Equals(""))
            {
                numResult = true;
            }
            else
            {
                decimal number3 = 0;
                bool canConvert = decimal.TryParse(numberVal, out number3);
                if (canConvert == true)
                {
                    numResult = true;
                }
                else
                    numResult = false;
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            numResult = false;
        }
        return numResult;
    }
    string correctNum;
    private void tBox_NumTester_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {


        if(checkTextisNumber(tBox_NumTester.Text))
        {
            correctNum = tBox_NumTester.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            tBox_NumTester.Text = correctNum;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had created a **Re-Usable Textbox Extension** class for all sorts of validations and thought about sharing it.

All you need to do is raise a **TextChange event** and then call the Validate method. It looks like this:

```
private void tbxAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    tbxAmount.Validate(TextValidator.ValidationType.Amount);
}
```

Here is the extension class:

```
public static class TextValidator
{
    public enum ValidationType
    {
        Amount,
        Integer
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validate a textbox on text change.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tbx"></param>
    /// <param name="validationType"></param>
    public static void Validate(this TextBox tbx, ValidationType validationType)
    {
        PerformValidation(tbx, validationType);
        tbx.Select(tbx.Text.Length, 0);
    }


    private static void PerformValidation(this TextBox tbx, ValidationType validationType)
    {
        char[] enteredString = tbx.Text.ToCharArray();
        switch (validationType)
        {
            case ValidationType.Amount:
                tbx.Text = AmountValidation(enteredString);
                break;

            case ValidationType.Integer:
                tbx.Text = IntegerValidation(enteredString);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        tbx.SelectionStart = tbx.Text.Length;
    }



    private static string AmountValidation(char[] enteredString)
    {
        string actualString = string.Empty;
        int count = 0;
        foreach (char c in enteredString.AsEnumerable())
        {
            if (count >= 1 && c == '.')
            { actualString.Replace(c, ' '); actualString.Trim(); }
            else
            {
                if (Char.IsDigit(c))
                {
                    actualString = actualString + c;
                }

                if (c == '.')
                {
                    actualString = actualString + c; count++;
                }

                else
                {
                    actualString.Replace(c, ' ');
                    actualString.Trim();
                }
            }
        }
        return actualString;
    }


    private static string IntegerValidation(char[] enteredString)
    {
        string actualString = string.Empty;
        foreach (char c in enteredString.AsEnumerable())
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                actualString = actualString + c;
            }
            else
            {
                actualString.Replace(c, ' ');
                actualString.Trim();
            }
        }
        return actualString;
    }
}
```

[You can find the full code here](https://gist.github.com/zaagan/e1a87ec3d411ba39f0d7d1e7e52660f8#file-textbox-validator)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply prevent adding non-numerical chars by this simple code

```
 if (long.TryParse(TextBox.Text,out long isparsable))
        {
          // your code to handle numbers
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox.Text="Only Numbers Allowed";
            TextBox.Focus();
            TextBox.SelectAll();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a RegularExpressionValidator:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
                        ControlToValidate="TextBoxNum" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Only numbers allowed"
                        ValidationExpression="\d+">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and crudest way is to use a combobox instead of textbox with ReadOnly. But of course its only useful if you are expecting the user to use a decent and reasonable set of whole numbers, not try to touch infinity.

Answer (score -1):

Working solution for WPF & a simple `TextChangedEventArgs`.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var TextBox = (sender as TextBox);

    // if not a numeric value, remove news characters
    if (Regex.IsMatch(TextBox.Text, "[^0-9]"))
    {
        foreach (TextChange Change in e.Changes)
        {
            TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text.Remove(Change.Offset, Change.AddedLength);

            TextBox.CaretIndex = Change.Offset;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about WinForms. There are no TextChangedEventArgs in WinForms' TextChanged event