# How to prevent the entry and appearance of non-numeric values in TextBox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I really need to prevent any non-numeric entry (Including paste) to my TextBox and also I want to prevent it from appearing on the TextBox before being erased, It would be wonderful if you put some hints regarding your code suggestion, because I'm just a beginner!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938329/how-to-filter-textbox-input-to-numeric-only duplicate

Comment: what disaster lies in store if they do enter a numeral?

Comment: I have viewed those threads before asking my questions, and I'm pretty sure that they are missing one of my points! (Preventing paste in the field) @Saechel

Comment: I can't understand you @Plutonix

Answer (score 0):

### Edited : added <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> handling and opimized Keypress event.

You could use this code, wich prevent numeric values from being handled :

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then ' Check if the value is a number
        e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

and for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> handling you can use this code :

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    ' Checking if control + v is clicked or Shift + Insert is clicked
    If (e.Control AndAlso Char.ToLower(ChrW(e.KeyValue)) = "v"c) Or (e.Shift AndAlso e.KeyValue = Keys.Insert) Then
        e.Handled = True
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not working, for sorrow!

Comment: Change `Handles textbox1.Keypress` to `handles yourtextbox.Keypress`

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to the following links:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?570438-Restrict-TextBox-to-only-certain-characters-numeric-or-symbolic

http://www.codigofacilito.com/videos/visual_basic_net_parte_funcion_para_recibir_solo_caracteres_curso_vbnet

If you still have any doubt, let me know.