# Prevent users from entering letters for all the textboxes

Tags: vb.net

So I've created a calculator that computes your grades into your general average. But I have one problem, what if the user entered letters in each textboxes instead of numbers? I want to prevent them to use letters. So what're the codes for restricting the user from entering letters? I just need a code for a button. I will appreciate the help!

I've tried all the codes from the websites but all of them didn't work.

```vb
        If emptyTextBoxes.Any Then
            MsgBox("Please fill all the boxes before you press 'Compute'.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "GWA Calculator")
        ElseIf Math.Text.Count(Function(c) Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) > 0 Or Eng.Text.Count(Function(c) Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) > 0 Or
            Sci.Text.Count(Function(c) Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) > 0 Or Fil.Text.Count(Function(c) Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) > 0 Or
            TL.Text.Count(Function(c) Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) > 0 Or IC.Text.Count(Function(c) Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) > 0 Or
            MAP.Text.Count(Function(c) Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) > 0 Or Araling.Text.Count(Function(c) Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) > 0 Or
            ES.Text.Count(Function(c) Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) > 0 Then
            MsgBox("One of the boxes has invalid characters", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "GWA Calculator")
        ElseIf (Math.Text.Length <> 2) Or (Eng.Text.Length <> 2) Or (Sci.Text.Length <> 2) Or (Fil.Text.Length <> 2) Or
            (TL.Text.Length <> 2) Or (IC.Text.Length <> 2) Or (MAP.Text.Length <> 2) Or (Araling.Text.Length <> 2) Or
            (ES.Text.Length <> 2) Then
            MsgBox("One of the boxes contains 1 or 3 digits. It must contain 2 digits only to be computed.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "GWA Calculator")
```

At the second If statement, it only restricts this kind of characters: "/, ^, #, etc." I want to restrict letters also. Anyone can help me?

P.S. I'm using Windows Forms.

Comment: Please explain. Is this an ASP.NET app or a desktop one? (WinForms, WPF)

Comment: I'm using Windows Form.

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938329).

Comment: Han, do I need to put this code in each of the texboxes? Because I need a code just for a button to get the job done for all the textboxes.

Comment: @Scott, you can write the code in a Sub then binds it to all the textboxes' events. Or you could write the code for each textbox but it's harder to maintain.

Comment: @Han, it's working now. Thanks for the help! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume I have 3 textboxes named txtMath, txtEnglish and txtScience for the numbers. When I click a button, the code checks if all the values in the textboxes can be parsed into numbers. Then another checks if all the numbers are between 0 and 99.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim mathScore, englishScore, scienceScore As Integer

    ' parse into numbers
    Dim scoresAreNumbers =
        Integer.TryParse(txtMath.Text, mathScore) AndAlso
        Integer.TryParse(txtEnglish.Text, englishScore) AndAlso
        Integer.TryParse(txtScience.Text, scienceScore)

    ' between 0 and 99
    Dim scoresAreValid =
        (mathScore >= 0 AndAlso mathScore < 100) AndAlso
        (englishScore >= 0 AndAlso englishScore < 100) AndAlso
        (scienceScore >= 0 AndAlso scienceScore < 100)

    If Not scoresAreNumbers Then
        MsgBox("One of the values are not numbers")
    ElseIf Not scoresAreValid Then
        MsgBox("One of the values are not between 0 and 99")
    Else
        Dim formatScores =
            "Math = {0}" & vbNewLine &
            "English = {1}" & vbNewLine &
            "Science = {2}"
        MsgBox(String.Format(formatScores, mathScore, englishScore, scienceScore))
    End If

End Sub
```