# Number TextBox in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Hi All

I Want Create a Numeric TextBox that Accept Numeric Keys And Then **Separate Number with Comma**.
Please Help Me for ...

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Fredrik Mörk @ IS Not Possible.I Do Not Want Make a Numeric TextBox Only!!!.I Want Make a Numeric TextBox with ThousandsSeparator.Please be careful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [`NumericUpDown` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx) and its `ThousandsSeparator` property.

Comment: How Can I Change Visible of Up/Down Button???

Comment: Don't.  Users like those buttons.

Comment: But I Want a TextBox For Input Currency Numbers!!! :(

Answer (score 0):

there is a full-featured sample DecimalTextBox control that can be installed from here:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/7/087e6a47-7306-4a5c-ad97-d1ffd58d712e/DecimalTextBox.msi

best regards