# Allow only Decimal Value

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2005, textbox, decimal

In window textbox, I'd like to just allow decimal only.

For example,
8.56

How to?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers) which may help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do using `double.TryParse`.

You can check your input on submit button as below mentioned ways.

```
            double m = 0;

            if (double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out m) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid Price");
                TextBox1.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                // Put your code here
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) Then
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

End Sub