# How to prevent a TextBox to accept Unicode control characters?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have scenarios that don't want the end user to input Unicode control characters to the Windows.Forms.TextBox, as you may know, if you right click a TextBox, a context menu will shown and the last menu item on this context menu is "Insert Unicode control character->", which can insert some Unicode control characters into the TextBox.

Is there anybody knows how to disable or hide these menus -> "Insert Unicode control character", "Show Unicode control characters".

Comment: You can disable the context menu all together by using `textBox1.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();` if that's an option.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you disable this context menu entry, the user can still enter all kinds of strange characters using copy & paste or using Alt-Numpad. If you want to restrict your input strictly to, say, A-Z, you can use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) control.

If you need more fine-grained control, you can handle the TextBox.KeyPress Event. An example of this technique can be found in the following SO question:

- [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Override your text box `ContextMenu`.

Design you own `ContextMenu` and implement only the functionality you want on it. and then assign that `contextMenu` to your `textBox`: `myTextBox.ContextMenu = myContextMenu;`

Answer (score 1):

To add to Jalal's answer,

```
var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy", (s, ea) => textBox1.Copy()));
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Paste", (s, ea) => textBox1.Paste()));
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Undo", (s, ea) => textBox1.Undo()));
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Select All", (s, ea) => textBox1.SelectAll()));
....

textBox1.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution.  I have couple of datagridview and textboxes, replacing everything concerns me a bit.  But I have the same app in vb where these menus are not displayed by default.