# By default make TextBox to accept numeric values only

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I referred to StackOverflow post here: [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

The problem with this style is that I need to add code or a method call to this code in every TextBox's Keypress event.

I want it in a different way. I want to modify the TextBox class itself in such a way that it can be made to accept either a string or a number depending upon criteria, as and when TextBox control is dropped from the ToolBox on the Form.

Comment: just create a user control with any of method in the attached ink. or you can extend the textbox server control and use those methods in the extended control

Comment: Yes you can. For more information please read [User Control.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a user control, simply derive a new class from TextBox.  Add a new class to your project and get started with code like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class NumberBox : TextBox {
    // insert code here
}
```

After you compile, the new control appears at the top of the toolbox.

Comment: Do I need to create this class in the same project or in a new project?

Comment: Same project.  Putting it in another project is okay too but you'll have to make the class *public*.