# RegEx.Replace in a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms, textbox

I have a Textbox and the following code to allow only numbers:

```
textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, "[^\\d]", "");
```

Now when I type another key than numbers, the focus goes to the beginning of the Textbox...What do I need to not let this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) instead, specifying the [Mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ask how to remove numbers. Ask how to make a textbox for numbers only: [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)