# textbox to accept integers

Tags: c#

I've found different help through this website but still can't seem to convert a string to int. I've tried many different ways. Here are two of them. On button_click I need to read the textboxes and convert them to int so I can perform standard logic on them. (a > b functions). Below the first section is what I'm using to force the use of numbers during entry into the text boxes.

```
    private void write_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        int mat_od1 = int.Parse(matod_box.Text); //Input string in wrong format.
        int mat_id1 = int.Parse(matid_box.Text);
        int fod1 = int.Parse(fod_box.Text);
        int fid1 = int.Parse(fid_box.Text);
        int hp1 = int.Parse(hp_box.Text);

        //This next section is just to show something else I've tried.

        decimal mat_od = Convert.ToDecimal(matod_box.Text); //Same error.
        decimal mat_id = Convert.ToDecimal(matid_box.Text);
        decimal fod = Convert.ToDecimal(fod_box.Text);
        decimal fid = Convert.ToDecimal(fid_box.Text);
        decimal hp = Convert.ToDecimal(hp_box.Text);
        decimal pass_od = mat_od;

    }

       private void fod_box_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int numinput = int.Parse(fod_box.Text);
            if (numinput < 1 || numinput > 500)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must enter a number between 0 and 500.");
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("You need to enter a number.");
            fod_box.Clear();

        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try setting a break point on your first **int.parse** statement.  See what the value of **matod_box.Text** is.

Comment: If you have these numeric textboxes in several places, you should consider making a user control, inherit textbox and add validation.

Comment: I do have multiple boxes so good point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of `int.Parse()` you should use `int.TryParse(string,out int)`
this way you would be able to chek the output and decide wether the string was correctly parsed or not

```
int i;string s="";
if(int.TryParse(s,out i))
{
 //use i
}
else
{
//show error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The int.parse conversion should work, as in this sample:

```
  string s = "111";
  int i;
  if (int.TryParse(s, out i))
  {
     Console.Write(i);
  }
  else
  {
      Console.Write("conversion failed");
  }
```

Are you sure you actually provide legal input for your ints? In any case, you should use TryParse like I did in my sample. Theres no need to use try..catch where you can use boolean methods provided by the framework, which will get you the same result..

Comment: Adding to YavgenyP's point, try..catch is a lot slower than Boolean comparisons.  Exceptions throw the processing flow all out of whack!  Avoid them if you can.

Comment: @Mark. It would be more accurate to say exceptions should be exceptional, so what you shouldn't do is use them for non-exceptional processing such as the text box has nowt in it.

Answer (score 1):

All depends on what you are allowing to be put in the text box.

If it might not be a string that can be converted to an integer, including blank, then something like

```
int value;
if (int.TryParse(SomeString, out value)
{
   // it is an int
}
else
{
  // it's not an int, so do nothing raise a message or some such.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `Int32.TryParse` in the button Click event handler as others have pointed out, you need to be careful what you're doing in the TextBox `Changed` event handler.  You're code here is flawed:

```
private void fod_box_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        int numinput = int.Parse(fod_box.Text); 
        ...
    } 
    catch (FormatException) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("You need to enter a number.");  
        fod_box.Clear(); 
    }
```

Calling foo_box.Clear() will clear any text from the textbox, calling the TextChanged handler to be executed again (unless the TextBox was already empty).  So if you enter a non-numeric value, your message box will be displayed twice - the first time when it attempts to parse your non-numeric value, the second time when it attempts to parse an empty string as a result of the call to Clear().

In general, I'd avoid doing validation in the Changed event handler.

Comment: Isn't there an Handled property on the EventArgs object that he can use if it's a non-number?

Comment: Thanks for the help! tryparse is working and Joe you are correct. The box does get displayed twice. whether I have the clear function or not because of the textchanged event.

Comment: "The box does get displayed twice. whether I have the clear function or not because of the textchanged " - you can get rid of this by explicitly allowing an empty string.