# How to Force only numeric values be allowed in maskedtextbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am fairly new to Winforms, and I would like to know how to use a MaskedTextBox to ensure that only numerical values(decimals included) are entered by the user.

I have tried the masked feature using "/^[-+]?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?$/" and was not successful with that. What I want, even if with an ordinary textbox, is to allow only numerals/decimal values

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/463299/250725

Comment: Have you tried the Mask property? `maskedtextbox1.Mask = "99999.99"`

Comment: RTFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

Comment: The mask property seems to restrict me to certain number of digits. For instance, if I provide 00000, user is only allowed to enter 5 single digits. I tried using the custom option with regex but I didn't get it right. So I am asking to learn how to go about restricting the input to simply numerals (double, float, integers, decimals) without restriction on length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted this NumericTextBox control: http://sanity-free.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=1205#p1205

If you want it apart of your toolbox, you'd probably create a new control based on a TextBox and paste the code in that link into the code section.

Here's my version of it.  I don't know how much I've modified it as I've had it a long time.

**NumericTextBox.Designer.cs:**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SeaRisenLib2.Controls
{
    partial class NumericTextBox : TextBox
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            //this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**NumericTextBox.cs**

```
// From: http://sanity-free.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=1205#p1205
// modified it slightly
//
/******************************************************/
/*          NULLFX FREE SOFTWARE LICENSE              */
/******************************************************/
/*  NumericTextBox Library                            */
/*  by: Steve Whitley                                 */
/*  © 2005 NullFX Software                            */
/*                                                    */
/* NULLFX SOFTWARE DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES,          */
/* RESPONSIBILITIES, AND LIABILITIES ASSOCIATED WITH  */
/* USE OF THIS CODE IN ANY WAY, SHAPE, OR FORM        */
/* REGARDLESS HOW IMPLICIT, EXPLICIT, OR OBSCURE IT   */
/* IS. IF THERE IS ANYTHING QUESTIONABLE WITH REGARDS */
/* TO THIS SOFTWARE BREAKING AND YOU GAIN A LOSS OF   */
/* ANY NATURE, WE ARE NOT THE RESPONSIBLE PARTY. USE  */
/* OF THIS SOFTWARE CREATES ACCEPTANCE OF THESE TERMS */
/*                                                    */
/* USE OF THIS CODE MUST RETAIN ALL COPYRIGHT NOTICES */
/* AND LICENSES (MEANING THIS TEXT).                  */
/*                                                    */
/******************************************************/
/* Changed by Carlos Montiers                         */
/* Decimal separator "." or "," depending on locale   */
/* Constructor for numericTextBox whith or without    */
/* negative range and number of decimals.             */
/* Does not allow the entry of non-numeric character  */
/* through alt + ascii code                           */
/* Permit use of tab key                              */
/* Version: 24-10-2008                                */
/******************************************************/

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SeaRisenLib2.Controls
{
    public partial class NumericTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;
        private int decimalNumbers;
        private bool hasNegatives;
        private string format;

        public delegate void D(NumericTextBox sender);
        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when Text changes
        /// </summary>
        public event D Changed = delegate { };

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor of a NumericTextBox, with negative number and 2 decimals.
        /// </summary>
        public NumericTextBox()
            : this(2, true)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor with parameters
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="decimalNumbers">number of decimals</param>
        /// <param name="hasNegatives">has negatives</param>
        public NumericTextBox(int decimalNumbers, bool hasNegatives)
            : base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DecimalNumbers = decimalNumbers;
            HasNegatives = hasNegatives;
            Format = Format;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Property of decimalNumbers
        /// </summary>
        public int DecimalNumbers
        {
            get
            {
                return decimalNumbers;
            }
            set
            {
                decimalNumbers = value > 0 ? value : 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Bindable Decimal Text
        /// </summary>
        public decimal DecimalText
        {
            get {
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
                    return 0;

                return Convert.ToDecimal(Text);
            }
            set { Text = value.ToString(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The string text value of the numeric text, use DecimalText to get the numeric value.
        /// </summary>
        public override string Text
        {
            get { return base.Text; }
            set
            {
                base.Text = value;
                Changed(this);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Property of hasNegatives
        /// </summary>
        public bool HasNegatives
        {
            get
            {
                return hasNegatives;
            }
            set
            {
                hasNegatives = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Property of format
        /// </summary>
        public string Format
        {
            get
            {
                return format;
            }
            set
            {
                format = "^";
                format += HasNegatives ? "(\\" + getNegativeSign() + "?)" : "";
                format += "(\\d*)";
                if (DecimalNumbers > 0)
                {
                    format += "(\\" + getDecimalSeparator() + "?)";
                    for (int i = 1; i <= DecimalNumbers; i++)
                    {
                        format += "(\\d?)";
                    }
                }
                format += "$";
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method PreProcessMessage
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="msg">ref Message</param>
        /// <returns>bool</returns>
        public override bool PreProcessMessage(ref Message msg)
        {
            if (msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                Keys keys = (Keys)msg.WParam.ToInt32();

                bool numbers = ModifierKeys != Keys.Shift
                                && (keys >= Keys.D0 && keys <= Keys.D9
                                    || (keys >= Keys.NumPad0 && keys <= Keys.NumPad9));


                bool dec = ModifierKeys != Keys.Shift
                            && (keys == Keys.Decimal
                                || keys == Keys.Oemcomma
                                || keys == Keys.OemPeriod);

                bool negativeSign = (keys == Keys.OemMinus && ModifierKeys != Keys.Shift)
                                    || keys == Keys.Subtract;

                bool home = keys == Keys.Home;
                bool end = keys == Keys.End;

                bool ctrlZ = keys == Keys.Z && ModifierKeys == Keys.Control;
                bool ctrlX = keys == Keys.X && ModifierKeys == Keys.Control;
                bool ctrlC = keys == Keys.C && ModifierKeys == Keys.Control;
                bool ctrlV = keys == Keys.V && ModifierKeys == Keys.Control;

                bool del = keys == Keys.Delete;
                bool bksp = keys == Keys.Back;

                bool tab = keys == Keys.Tab;

                bool arrows = keys == Keys.Up
                              || keys == Keys.Down
                              || keys == Keys.Left
                              || keys == Keys.Right;

                if (numbers || del || bksp || arrows || home || end
                    || ctrlC || ctrlX || ctrlV || ctrlZ)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (dec)
                    {
                        return DecimalNumbers <= 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (negativeSign)
                        {
                            return !HasNegatives;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (tab)
                            {
                                return base.PreProcessMessage(ref msg);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.PreProcessMessage(ref msg);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method WndProc
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="m">ref Message</param>
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
            {
                IDataObject obj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                string input = (string)obj.GetData(typeof(string));
                string pasteText = getPosibleText(input);

                if (!isValidadFormat(pasteText))
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)0;
                    return;
                }
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method OnKeyPress
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">KeyPressEventArgs</param>
        protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
            string keyInput = e.KeyChar.ToString();
            string inputText = getPosibleText(keyInput);

            if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
                || keyInput.Equals(getDecimalSeparator())
                || keyInput.Equals(getNegativeSign()))
            {
                e.Handled = !isValidadFormat(inputText);
            }
            else if (e.KeyChar == '\b'
                    || e.KeyChar == '\t'
                    || keyInput.Equals(Keys.Delete.ToString())
                    || keyInput.Equals(Keys.Home.ToString())
                    || keyInput.Equals(Keys.End.ToString()))
            {
                //Allow backspace, tab, delete, home, end
            }
            else if (e.KeyChar == 26
                     || e.KeyChar == 24
                     || e.KeyChar == 3
                     || e.KeyChar == 22)
            {
                // 26 : Allow Ctrl+Z | 24 : Allow Ctrl+X
                //  3 : Allow Ctrl+C | 22 : Allow Ctrl+V
            }
            else
            {
                //Disallow
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method OnTextChanged
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">System.EventArgs</param>
        protected override void OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (getFloatValue() < 0)
            {
                this.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }

            //If the decimal point is preceded by a no number is added zero
            if (this.Text.StartsWith(getNegativeSign() + getDecimalSeparator()))
            {
                this.Text = getNegativeSign() + "0" + this.Text.Substring(1);
                this.Select(3, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.Text.StartsWith(getDecimalSeparator()))
                {
                    this.Text = "0" + this.Text;
                    this.Select(2, 0);
                }
            }
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for validate text with format
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">text</param>
        /// <returns>is valid format</returns>
        private bool isValidadFormat(string text)
        {
            return Regex.IsMatch(text, Format);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for get deciamal separator
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Decimal Separator of current culture</returns>
        private string getDecimalSeparator()
        {
            return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for get negative sign
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Negative Sign of current culture</returns>
        private string getNegativeSign()
        {
            return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NegativeSign;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for get posible resulting text for input text
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">string with input text</param>
        /// <returns>posible text</returns>
        private string getPosibleText(string text)
        {
            string rText;
            rText = this.Text.Substring(0, SelectionStart);
            rText += text;
            rText += this.Text.Substring(SelectionStart + SelectionLength);
            return rText;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for get int value of text
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>int value</returns>
        public int getIntValue()
        {
            try
            {
                return (int)getFloatValue();
            }
            catch
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for get round int value of text
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>round int value</returns>
        public int getIntRoundValue()
        {
            try
            {
                return (int)Math.Round(getFloatValue());
            }
            catch
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for get float value of text
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>float value</returns>
        public float getFloatValue()
        {
            try
            {
                return float.Parse(this.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Why not just use a NumericUpDown?  Set your max and min values, number of decimal places, and away you go.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you! 2019 and I had no idea this control existed!

Comment: The NumericUpDown works fine for Byte, Short, Integer, Long and Decimal, but not for Single and Double.

Answer (score 3):

Masks for the MaskedTextBox aren't regex patterns; they use their own syntax.

The pattern you want is probably something like "999,990.9999". This requires the user to enter at least one digit, but they can enter any number from 0 to 999,999.9999 and with up to 4 decimals precision, and will automatically insert the thousands separator when needed.

Another thing you can do, similar to what the MaskedTextBox itself does, is override OnKeyPress to reject any character entered that would cause a Regex not to match:

```
public class RegexTextBox:TextBox
{
   [Category("Behavior")]
   public string RegexPattern {get;set;}

   protected override OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
   { 
      if (!Regex.IsMatch(this.Text + e.KeyChar, RegexPattern)) e.Handled = true;
      else base.OnKeyPress(e);
   }
}
```

You have to be careful when defining the pattern, because it will only work if what's been entered so far matches the pattern. However, it will work in your case, if you use a pattern like `"[0-9]{1,3}((,[0-9]{1,3})*(\.[0-9]*)?"`.

Answer (score 1):

thanks , working code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace System.Windows.Forms {
    public class RegexTextBox : TextBox {
        [Category("Behavior")]
        public string RegexPattern { get; set; }
        private bool DelOrBack = false;
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back || e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete) {
                DelOrBack = true;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e) {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(this.Text + e.KeyChar, RegexPattern) && !DelOrBack) {
                e.Handled = true;               
            }
            else {
                base.OnKeyPress(e);
            }

            DelOrBack = false;
        }
    }

    public class NumericTextBox : RegexTextBox {
        public NumericTextBox() {
            RegexPattern = "^[0-9]+$";
        }
    }
}
```