# How to set masked text box values to decimal numbers?

Tags: c#, winforms, decimal, maskedtextbox

I am new to C#
Here i am using `masked textbox` and set the mask as `00.0`. And in database respective field is stored in `decimal(3,1)` 
while retrieving to masked text box it will give inaccurate values 
if i stored
     12.3 , 23.8, 45.7 these type of values i got solution 
But instead of these if we use 1.3 , 3.5, 5.6 i 
                                   got in my masked text box as 13.0, 35.0, 56.0 ....
how to handle this exception?
sorry..! for my bad English
advance thanks

Comment: have you tried changing your mask to 0.##?

Comment: i have set the mask as #0.0 and 0.## but it gives the same result.

Comment: I think your question is a very close duplicate of this! --> [winform — Force only numeric values be allowed in maskedtextbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758683/winform-force-only-numeric-values-be-allowed-in-maskedtextbox) Have a look at this as well --> [Code project Quick Answers](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/207628/MaskedTextBox-mask-for-decimal-real-float)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While setting back the `MaskedTextBox`, try converting the `decimal` value according to some format:

```
maskedTextBox1.Text = value.ToString("0#.#");
```

This way you will get **01.3** instead of **13.0**

Comment: may i know what is `value` here?

Comment: i got error like   cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: Assuming value is of type decimal retrieved from the DB. Try converting from Decimal to String.

Comment: On a side note, thank you for flagging low quality answers.  If you see something that should be a comment, or link only, could you please flag them as "Not An Answer"?  It helps the moderators in that we have other workflow options to make it easier to process these flags.