# How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers by masking?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have got a text box in WinForms which is just for entering phone numbers. how can I do it by just masking it.
I have used if instruction but i want to use the mask.
actually my biggest problem was that I didn't know even where is the mask text box.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers), [How to Force only numeric values be allowed in maskedtextbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758683/how-to-force-only-numeric-values-be-allowed-in-maskedtextbox) and many others. Please use the search. :-)

Comment: I have seen that question before. it used the if instruction. I wanna do it by masking.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `if`, but for masking see see the second link. Please show some effort from your side. :-)

Comment: I have to say that if you use if instruction when you have more than 5 or 6 forms it takes a lot of time that your program perform its task.

Comment: That does not seem to make any sense. An few `if`'s won't be considerably slower or faster than a masked textbox, they both evaluate in at most a few miliseconds.

Comment: but it does have different. any way thanks for your help. i will show more effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to Add MaskedTextBox in .NET

Steps

Click on Toolbox in the left-side Bar
Navigate and Find MaskedTextBox .NET Component
Double click on it to get it on Windows Form

Steps

Click on Properties in Right-sidebar. It appears as shown in the image below
Click on Set Mask or directly click on Browse button
A dialog box appears put value according to your requirement in Mask labeled Textbox
Click Ok

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MaskedTextBox` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx).
**Update**
See `Mask` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Remarks section for more details.

Comment: would you please write me the full code.\

Comment: Immediate OP -1 for 'please write me the full code'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Char.IsDigit()` function to check the user input.

Try This:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: I don't want if instruction. it isn't useful when you have more than 5 or 6 form