# Create a textbox of type="number"

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I have a custom control which uses `System.Windows.Form.Textbox` as the underlying text box.

I want to change that type to `type="number"` however I don't see a way to do this.

The end goal is to have an input field which, when clicked on a smartphone browser, will give you only numeric keys to enter rather than the full keyboard.

It is possible to restrict the input to numbers only using `JavaScript`, but that is not what I want. I specifically need the keyboard to open with only numbers on it. If there is an alternative way to achieve this than setting `type="number"` then that should work as well.

Comment: Maybe create a number only textbox as mentioned in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758683/how-to-force-only-numeric-values-be-allowed-in-maskedtextbox        Specifically the very last comment

Comment: @ashwin Are you suggesting to use NumericUpDown instead? Does that control generate gtml for input type="number"?

Comment: A few suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398356/render-asp-net-textbox-as-html5-input-type-number

Answer (score 0):

You can add `type="number"` to an ASP.NET TextBox and it will render with that attribute.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" type="number" />
```

Depending on ASP.NET version it will either render with both `type="text"` and `type="number"` (v2.0 - v3.5) or just `type="number"` (v4.0+).

If you wanted to add this conditionally in your code-behind, you could:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("type", "number");
```

Comment: In asp.net 3.5 
`<form runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" Type="number"/>
 </form>`
produces `<input name="ctl06" type="text">`

Comment: Just tried in v3.5 here and `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" type="number"></asp:TextBox>` results in `<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" type="number" />` for me. Not sure why it is different for you.