# How to type the number in masked textbox in web browser control C#

Tags: c#, automation, webbrowser-control, maskedtextbox, maskedinput

I want to enter the numeric value in the masked textbox.

[image]

I have written the following code

```
numericElement.SetAttribute("value", "123456789");
```

[image]

It displays the value in the textbox but when I place the cursor on the textbox it gets disappear.

[image]

How can I type the number in masked textbox in web browser control C#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758683/how-to-force-only-numeric-values-be-allowed-in-maskedtextbox

Comment: I need to set a value for the masked text box in the web browser control

Comment: You aren't providing enough information, so people are confused. Web browser control? So are you using ASP.NET? What type is numericElement?

Comment: @robbpriestley, Web browser control in C# windows application.  numericElement is a variable name for HTMLELEMENT