# How to make rule for html input textbox with jquery

Tags: html, inputbox

I want my textbox in HTML page only accept number from 0 to 10, also accept: 0.5, 1.2, ...
Thanks alot

Comment: You're probably going to need to use javascript. Here's an SA post which deals with the same issue that may help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
function checkfloat(e,field){
     if (!(((e.keyCode>=48)&&(e.keyCode<=57))||(e.keyCode==46)))
     {
        e.keyCode=0;                   
     }     
 if (e.keyCode==46)
 {
    var patt1=new RegExp("\\.");        
    var ch =patt1.exec(field);       
    if(ch==".")
    {
        e.keyCode=0;
    }                        
 }
} 
</script>
<input type="text" onkeypress="checkfloat(event, this.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex for doing that!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 number input type can do this:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" />
```

However browser support for this is still poor. Only [Chrome, Safari and Opera](http://caniuse.com/input-number) support this at this point in time.

Give it a test in Chrome though.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BbX4V/)