# Windows 8 - make TextBox accepts only numbers

Tags: windows-8, textbox, numbers

I read some great posts on [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

However, I couldn't find the same thing working in Windows 8, there is no Key Press event handler. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "OnKeyPressed" but you have "KeyDown" event.

```
<TextBox KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown_1"/>
```

And then in C#:

```
 private void TextBox_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        //check IsDigit.
    }
```

Comment: never thought it was that simple

Comment: but you do not have possibility to filter chars like $%^&