# masked TextBox input validation for alphanumeric

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have used the following site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkx4h3az.aspx 
to validate for entering 8 digit number,

I then tried validating this way so that only alphanumeric (letters) values are allowed to be input into the textbox but it did not work.

Do you have to apply a different method for allowing only letters? If so how?

thanks

Comment: Please take a look at this thread: [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Comment: [Alphanumeric TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53681247/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

Did this off the top of my head, but it should get you started... This seems like a common question.  If this doesn't work then keep searching SO and you will find the answer.

```
 Regex regex = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]");
 Match match = regex.Matches(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Alphanumeric means letters **and** numbers. If you want letters only, you have to use "L" in your mask. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask?view=net-5.0) for reference.

Alternatively you can check input in text changed event. This works for conventional TextBox too (for masked textbox you have to change TextBox to MaskedTextBox). See code below:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (!tb.Text.All(char.IsLetter))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Only Letters are allowed.", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        tb.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Code requires `using System.Linq;`

Comment: TextChanged is too late. Take a look at [Alphanumeric TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53681247/3110834).