# How to get the integer value in TextBox?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have one  Text Box in windows application. This  Text Box only allowed the integer value not string. Can anybody have solution ?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers).

Comment: Use regular expresions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it.

```
public int GetIntValue(TextBox tb)
{
    try
    {
        return Convert.toInt32(tb.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //This is called if the converting failed for some reason
    }

    return 0; //This should only return 0 if the textbox does not contain a valid integer value
}
```

Use it like this:

```
int number = GetIntValue(textBox1);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

You use this code and get your integer value.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from [C# How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Hope it will help you.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) 
            && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
            && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' 
            && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```