# Issue with Masked Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I asked how to format a Textbox to accept only numbers but was adviced to use a Masked Textbox and set the Mask Property but doing this i have encountered some Problems

1) The masked textbox requires a maximum number of data a user can type to be set, but i want the user to be able to enter unlimited data

2) The masked textbox shows an Underscore

[image: Underscore]

how do i remove this??

Any help will be appreciated sorry if this question is not well structured

Comment: This is almost an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  Instead you should have probably just searched for [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers).

Comment: If you want unlimited data entry just set to `int.Max`, as they wont be able to enter more than that anyway on a 32bit platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular textbox and just handle the KeyPressed Event.  This will also prevent Copy and paste,  This was taken from another post here,  [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)  .

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) 
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
        && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Scratch that does not handle copy and paste but gets you further along than before!

Comment: If you want to prevent copy and paste to this field you can make the shortcuts enabled property false on that textbox.

Comment: Or simply handle the keydown event and check if the contents in the clipboard is a digit, then just append the text depending where the caret is. That way you will still be able to keep the copy/paste functionality.

Answer (score 1):

By default MaskedTextbox's [PromptChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.promptchar.aspx) is set to "_" (underscore). Simply change its PromptChar property to " " (space)