# How do you make an event happen when text is entered into a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, events, textbox

I am making an EPOS and I would like continually take input from a textbox but the textbox must only take the value if it is validated and is on a list of variables.

I just need to know what event that would be on the textbox

Comment: You can take TextChanged/KeyPress/KeyDown event and compare the value with your list of variables

Comment: Windows/web/something else?

Comment: EPOS: Embedded PowerPC Operating System ;)

Comment: See I was thinking "Electronic Point of Sale"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For validation, `KeyPress` event is appropriate.
You can control which characters can be entered in the text box.

Here's an example:
[How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event.