# Visual C# Exception Handling(input only numbers and ".")

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I am currently working on my Windows Console app. Is there any way to let the users only input numbers and one dot in the text box, inside the `TextChanged` part?

```
private void Input_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers

Answer (score 1):

This is one way (See more on MSDN TryParse):

```
  string inValue="123.1"; //for example
  decimal number;
  bool result = decimal.TryParse(inValue, out number);
  if (result)
  {
     //The entered number is valid number (1 decimal)         
  }
  else
  {
     //bad input number.
     if (inValue == null) inValue = ""; 
     Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", inValue);
  }
```

Comment: How about taking care of the current culture? In Germany, e.g. the decimal separator is a `,` not a `.`.

Comment: Plus, `Int32` doesn't sound like the way to parse _decimal_ numbers.

Comment: @Uwe Keim, you are correct. I am not sure the culture was part of the question though. I assume the current culture will be the default. I guess one would possibly use System.Globalization to set a specific culture as a global setting in the application.