# Want to set textbox property that can accommodate 1 number

Tags: c#

I created 4 textboxes where I will key in my binary digits, one digit on one textbox.
Now, I want to make sure that all the text boxes have a property **MaxLength** and that it must only accept digits not chars and size must accommodate a number/digit.

Comment: What have `YOU` tried sofar?

Comment: Is it a Web forms, Winforms, WPF, MVC........ application?

Comment: Hi @nutty, C# tag alone is not sufficient for a question like this. You should add the tag that specifies your application type like WinForms or WPF to the question so others can understand your context better.

Answer (score 0):

You should use TextBox.MaxLength = 1 and also engage OnKeyDown event to stop users to enter any other digits except 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this one for each textbox:

```
TextBox myTextBox = new TextBox();
myTextBox.MaxLength = 50;
```

And here is a similar post regarding texbox input that accepts only digits:[How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Set `TextBox.MaxLength` and use the `OnKeyPress` event to apply your restictions

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) )
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```