# TextBox enable to add only numbers - C#

Tags: c#, textbox

I have read a lot of code examples in this subject but it doesnt work. It should be no problem but it failed in my project where in other people project it work.
I have text box in C# that should be contains only numbers.
In my project if i have a text box with text :

```
-----------------------
|         32          |
|                     |
----------------------|
```

and i add a char " T" my resualt is :

```
-----------------------
|         T3          |
|                     |
----------------------|
```

It remove the first char instead the last char
My code :

```
private void txt_NumOfIkun_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char charAdded = e.KeyChar;

        if (txt_NumOfIkun.TextLength > 1)
                txt_NumOfIkun.Text = txt_NumOfIkun.Text.Substring(0, txt_NumOfIkun.TextLength - 1);
            else
                txt_NumOfIkun.Text= "";
    }
```

Comment: why not use a NumericUpDown instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9')
{
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks it works. but, how i do that i can delet number? because only the number in the keyboard works.

Comment: I got it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers