# TextBox accepts only int

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a problem with my textbox. I wanted that one can manually set the interval of the x- and y-axis for a chart in the GUI over two textboxes. That works but when I type a char in or when I typed an int in and delete it, the program crashes immediately and I get a System.FormatException (without clicking the button to accept the changes). How can I solve it that one can just type in different signs without immediately crashing the program? My code below:

```
public void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     x_axis_num = Convert.ToInt32(xAxisBox.Text, usC);
}

private void yAxisBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    y_axis_num = Convert.ToInt32(yAxisBox.Text);
}
```

That gets passed to another event:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = x_axis_num;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = y_axis_num;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Comment: show what event assigns the chart intervals. @Shaharyar link will help you for the character part but since you are concerned with backspaces as well you have to validate that on your assignment event

Comment: Its the event which occurs when I click the button to draw the graph. So when I change the axis intervals and click the button it works fine. How do I validate that?

Comment: @uzi42tmp Problem is you enter something other than `int` which through an unhanded `FormatException` which means it can not parse that value to `int`.

Comment: You said the program crashes immediately after typing a character so i thought the event was running always.  Then shaharyar is right you can get your answer in his link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line `x_axis_num = Convert.ToInt32(xAxisBox.Text, usC);`, you are taking whatever is in the text box and try to convert it to an integer value.

What do you think the conversion of "Hey, I'm not a number!" will do? It will crash horribly, basically because that text is not, and never will be, a number.

Instead, you can use the [Int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method which will take any text and TRY to convert it to a number.

If the conversion is successful, then no problem. If it was not successful, then you get a `false` value on a flag indicating the text could not be converted.

Example:

```
int number;

bool result = Int32.TryParse(YourTextBox.Text, out number);
```

If the conversion is successful, then number has the value, otherwise, result is false so do something like this then:

```
if(result)
{
    xAxisBox.Text = number.ToString();
    x_axis_num = number;
}
else
{
    xAxisBox.Text = string.Empty;

    // Be careful here with what you set. 
    // This is the value you will set when the Text box has a non numeric value!
    x_axis_num = 0;    
}
```

Comment: He tells me that the TryParse method has not legal values when I write it that way - EDIT: sry had an error in it

Comment: In which event do you propose he place this?

Comment: I would say into the the both x-axis and y-axis events? or am I wrong? I get another error in "xAxisBox.Text = number;" - he tells me that a convertion of int to string isn't possible.

Comment: @uzi42tmp You are right and I was missing a ToString on the number when assigning it to the text property. I updated the answer.

Comment: Wait a minute! Now he doesn't load the values in! When I click the button to change the axis he does nothing :/

Comment: Did you assign the number value to your x_axis_num and y_axis_num variables after setting it to the textbox?

Comment: How to do that exactly? now I changed num to num_x and num_y and when I try to assign he sais I can't convert bool to string even when I try it - EDIT: Ok it was my fault! Now it works correctly! Thanks again :)

Comment: Updated the answer to show you the full correct code :)