# C# Digit-only TextBoxes in a GroupBox.

Tags: c#, events, textbox, groupbox

I'm using WinForms and I'm struggling trying to make all the `TextBoxes` from a `GroupBox` to accept only digits as user input. Is there a way to raise the KeyPress event for all the `TextBoxes` in a `GroupBox`? Something like this maybe:

```
private void groupBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
}
```

I'm quite new at this, so please bear with me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider using a NumericUpDown control instead of a TextBox. It handles the numeric filtering for you automatically, and also gives the user a more intuitive interface. But if you want to use a TextBox, the clean object-oriented way to do it is to subclass the built-in TextBox control, add numeric filtering logic, and then use your subclassed control in place of the standard TextBox control everywhere you need it.

Comment: what @CodyGray suggests is a nice and clean option but you could use the void that you posted here for each textbox by binding all the keypress events to that same void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
    private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
        (e.KeyChar != '.'))
    {
            e.Handled = true;
    }

    // only allow one decimal point
    if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The source answer from here [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Comment: I've already tried it. It seems, like if GroupBoxes don't have the KeyPress event at all, although the MSDN states that they do.

Comment: You can set KeyPress event of all the TextBox control to this groupBox1_KeyPress, instead of set the event of groupbox control.
For example : textBox1.KeyPress += groupBox1_KeyPress, textBox2.KeyPress += groupBox1_KeyPress ...

Comment: Thanks so much! Not only did it work, but it made me understand event handlers a bit better :)