# what datatype should i use if i want to avoid any crash on my program?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

i have a shopping cart website and i have a track your order function wherein the admin can type in a "number" and transaction details will be viewed. however, i am trying to break my program and tried to input letters(abc) inside the transaction text box. it showed me an error that the input string was not in the correct format. should i use char? string? any references and answers are highly appreciated. :)

here is my code on the button in my transaction text box.

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtTransactionNo.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            rblOrderDetails.Visible = true;
            ShowOrderDetails(rblOrderDetails.SelectedValue, Convert.ToInt32(txtTransactionNo.Text));
        }
        else
        {
            rblOrderDetails.Visible = false;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Panel3.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

and here where i declared the transactionNO text box

```
public string TransactionNoText
    {
        get { return txtTransactionNo.Text; }
        set { txtTransactionNo.Text = value; }
    }
```

Comment: See this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers

Comment: You cannot convert a `string` to an `integer` unless it is in the proper format. A better approach would be to add validation to your textbox control before sending it to the server.

Comment: @TDG thanks for the reference. i understand how it works but seems like its not available in the toolbox? (numericupdown) im using VS 2010.

Comment: @jmc thanks for the response. i have checked all of the validations and i think no one fits this issue. i am avoiding my program to crash when i input letters to the txtbox. any references? thanks again :)

Comment: Why don't you use ajax Masked textbox controls like this: http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Comment: thanks @NeverHopeless. i only need like 1 to 2 digit number. i think ill go  with the numericupdown but its not showing in the toolbox. any idea?

Comment: Perhaps this: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/ajax-control-toolkit/how-do-i-use-the-numericupdown-extender-control

Answer (score 0):

instead of directly converting to a number using `Convert.ToInt32()`, use int.TryParse()`.

int result=0;

```
if(int.TryParse(txtTransactionNo.Text,out result))
```

{

```
ShowOrderDetails(rblOrderDetails.SelectedValue,result);
```

}

Comment: what if it is based on user input?

Comment: i have an error when i tried ShowOrderDetails(rblOrderDetails.SelectedValue, int.TryParse(txtTransactionNo.Text));

Comment: it will throw an exception if it is not able to parse your `txtTransactionNo.Text` to `int`. TryParse() returns a boolean

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod: You can use TryParse , check the result, and only if bool you can call your function.

Comment: @Paolo Duhaylungsod  please look into the updated answer.hope this will help you

Comment: thanks @Joseph! ill try it out. do you have any idea where i can get the numericupdown function?

Comment: i have @jmc lol. i tried in my toolbox as well, its not thereeeee:(

Comment: wow! I know it's not there. but googling `installing ajax control toolkit` made it appear on my toolbox. magic? I don't think so!

Comment: im sorry @jmc. thank you always for your help. Godbless :)

Comment: youre very infomative. hope you will still help me in my future queries. more power :) @jmc