# How to prohibit write letters in a textbox? C#

Tags: c#

I am learning to code in c#, so if I do not explain everything ok, do not kill me!
I an practising with c#, trying to do a very simple calculator(only add), but when I write a letter(not number), the program crash because the textbox is saving data in a Int. I ask how to prohibit writting letters, but no numbers, so it doesn´t crash. Thanks! Sorry for not commenting the code, i am still forgetting doing that!
Here is the relevant code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace calculadora
{
public partial class Suma : Form
{
    public Suma()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Suma_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public int resultadoint, op1, op2; //declaracion de variables.
    public string resultado; //declaracion de variable a mostrar.

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        resultadoint = op1 + op2;
        resultadotext.Text = resultadoint.ToString();
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //solo indicador de suma
    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void operador1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //se intruduce aquí el primer operador, op1.
    {
        op1 = int.Parse(operador1.Text);
    }

    private void operador2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //se intruduce aquí el segundo operador, op2.
    {
        op2 = int.Parse(operador2.Text);

    }
}
```

My code do Not use KeyPress.

Comment: This has been already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers

Comment: Thanks, but that post do not work with my code.

Comment: that other post is a standard way of filtering out unwanted characters.  I suggest you spend some time studying it.  You should be able to incorporate it into your code pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks you all, now I haven´t any problem! Thanks!