# How to get a number from a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 text boxes, and I want the user to put any number into it to get an answer.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
int firstNumber;
int secondNumber;
int thirdNumber;
int answer;
firstNumber = 100;
secondNumber = 75;
thirdNumber = 50;
answer = firstNumber + secondNumber * thirdNumber;
MessageBox.Show(answer.ToString());
```

Comment: You can convert the value of textbox using `Convert.ToInt32()` method.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a string to int, use [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int firstNumber = Int32.Parse(firstNumberTextBox.Text);
//throws exception if not convertible
```

or

```
int firstNumber;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(firstNumberTextBox.Text, out firstNumber);
//return false if not convertible
```

or

```
int firstNumber;
result = Convert.ToInt32(firstNumberTextBox.Text);
//throws exception if not convertible
```

> Using the `Convert.ToInt32(String)` method is equivalent to passing value to the
>   `Int32.Parse(String)` method. value is interpreted by using the
>   formatting conventions of the current thread culture.
>
> If you prefer
>   not to handle an exception if the conversion fails, you can call the
>   `Int32.TryParse` method instead. It returns a `Boolean` value that
>   indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.

You can use `int` instead of `Int32`.

So in your case, it seems `int.TryPars` better fits:

```
int firstNumber;
int secondNumber;
int thirdNumber;
int answer;
int.TryParse(firstNumberTextBox.Text, out firstNumber);
int.TryParse(secondNumberTextBox.Text, out secondNumber);
int.TryParse(thirdNumberTextBox.Text, out thirdNumber);
answer = firstNumber + secondNumber * thirdNumber;
MessageBox.Show(answer.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how to use [Convert.ToInt32()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) method,

```
int firstNumber;
int secondNumber;
int thirdNumber;
int answer;
firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
thirdNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
answer = firstNumber + secondNumber* thirdNumber;
MessageBox.Show(answer.ToString());
```

but the problem in here is when the value of `textbox` is not convertible to integer your application will give an error.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already `Int32.TryParse` will protect you from an exception if the user types in a value that's not a number.

But I would advise to prevent the user from typing in invalid values. You can achieve that by handling the `KeyPress` event

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
        (e.KeyChar != '.'))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    // only allow one decimal point
    if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/463335/3330348) for more details.

This way you will make sure the input is valid and it's safe to use `Int32.Parse` or `Convert.ToInt32`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Form or Window where you have 3 `TextBoxes` naming `firstNumber`, `secondNumber`, `thirdNumber` and than the calculations could be done something like this

```
MessageBox.Show((Convert.ToInt32(firstNumber.Text) +
                 Convert.ToInt32(secondNumber.Text) *
                 Convert.ToInt32(thirdNumber.Text)).ToString());
```

Less code to do the same thing (and possibly better).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Form or Window where you have 3 TextBoxes naming firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber.
2. Test for digits:

> ```
> private void TxtBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
>     {
>          if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
>               e.Handled = true;
>     }
>  //To allow for backspace:
>     private void TxtBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
>     {
>          if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)))
>               e.Handled = true;
>     }
> ```

If you want to add other allowable keys, look at the Keys enumeration and use the approach above.
3. To convert a string to int, use Int32.Parse.
4. Add & display the answer.