# Delete all non-digits from textbox

Tags: c#

I have textbox1 where i enter number. Example: 123
I also have textbox2 where the sum is shown. Example: 6 (1+2+3)

What i need is. If there is only numbers in my textbox1, then everything is fine and i'm getting sum.
If there is something more than numbers like 1a2b3c i want the programm to show message box with Warning and a text. Delete all non-digits? If the guy press Yes, then it does delete abc and only 123 is left. If no, then Error shows up.

My code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int cipari = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

        int summa = 0;
        for (int n = cipari; n > 0; summa += n % 10, n /= 10) ;

        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Delete all non-digits?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            textBox2.Text = summa.ToString();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Error! You can't sum non-digits!";
        }


    }
```

Comment: [Why not just make the textbox numbers only with a simple check?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Comment: `Convert.ToInt()` will crash if they entered a non-digit, so the rest of your code will never even take place. Use `Int.TryParse(string s, out int result)`. If it returns false, then you know they have entered invalid data. Then just loop over the string, find any non-digit (`!Char.IsDigit()`) and remove it, if so.

Comment: Can you write your answer? I didn't really understand much cause i never really used Int.TryParse :(

Answer (score 1):

Simply check for the prescence of non-digit characters:

```
foreach(Char c in textBox1.Text) {
    if( !Char.IsDigit( c ) ) {
        MessageBox.Show("Non-digits detected");
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd program flow honestly.  But you can do it like:

```
if(!textBox2.Text.All(char.IsDigit)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Delete all non-digits?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        textBox2.Text = string.Concat(textBox2.Text.Where(char.IsDigit));
    }
    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        textBox2.Text = "Error! You can't sum non-digits!";
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it shows error something like this: system.windows.forms.textbox does not contain a definition for 'all'

Comment: @RobertsŠensters try `!textBox2.Text.All`

Comment: whoops yep sorry typo, fixed @RobertsŠensters

Answer (score 0):

if you only want numbers then you can use a small function the scrub and warn the user on the textchanged event of each effected text box.  This will show a warning to the user and then remove the invalid character.

```
private void validateText(TextBox tb)
        {
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(tb.Text, @"[^0-9]"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
                tb.Text = tb.Text.Remove(tb.Text.Length - 1);
                tb.Refresh();
                tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length;
                tb.SelectionLength = 0;
            }
        }
```

use:

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            validateText(textbox1);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Why to delete numbers every time user enters alphabets, I guess the best practice is to never let the user enter anything else than a number.

First create a function that checks if the text entered is integer or not 
like this :

```
private bool IsNumber(string text)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9.-]+"); //regex that matches if the text contains only numbers
        return regex.IsMatch(text);
    }
```

Then Use the textbox's PreviewTextInput event to stop the user from entering nothing but integers (decimal and -) too.

```
private void Button_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = IsNumber(e.Text);
    }
```

It's important to set the e.handled to the **IsNumber** function as here only it checks using this method if the input string is acceptable or not and prevents the user from entering it.