# Prevent converting an invalid strings to an integer

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm making a guessing game where the program generates a random number from 0 to 10 and the user tries to guess it.
I want the user to input an integer in a Text Area.
Then I convert the input to integer. Here comes the problem:
How do I do something if the input is an unconvertable string? Like "asdf". I want the program to output "I asked for a number!! not word dumbass!"
but C# converts even things like "Aadsda" to 0.. what do i do?

This is what I tried:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int.TryParse(textBox_Guess.Text, out guess);
            //IF STATEMENTS TO CHECK HOW CLOSE THE USER'S GUESS IS
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Since all strings are converted, this block is never executed

            label_Reveal.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            label_Reveal.Text = "Your input is invalid!";
            label_Reveal.Show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe TryParse returns a boolean value which tells you if it was successful.

Comment: BTW: A littlebit offtopic, but the reason why TryParse returns a zero even if the method failed to convert it, is, because the default value of an integer is 0

Comment: okay that made sense.LESSON:  TryParse is a BOOLEAN

Comment: @Chris don't wanna spam but there's a hell of a similarity between your account and my account, my name and rep are the same!! :D

Comment: Please don't ever do `catch (Exception)` - it's even worse than using `goto` and just hides buggy code.

Comment: i deleted my answer because i found other answers more helpful. but it worth a look at here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers

Answer (score 2):

```
if(int.TryParse(textBox_Guess.Text, out guess)){
    //successfully parsed, continue work
}
else {
    //here you can write your error message.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TryParse returns a boolean. With the boolean you can decide, whether it was sucessfully parsed or not.

```
if(int.TryParse(..)
{
      //If parsed sucessfully
}
else
{
      //Wasn't able to parse it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The TryXYZ pattern, with functions like TryParse, attempts to avoid having to rely on exceptions when parsing strings into other types. A more appropriate usage of the function to accomplish what you are attempting could be implemented like so:

```
var guessString = textBox_Guess.Text;
int guessParsed;
var success = int.TryParse(guessString, out guessParsed);
if(!success) {
    label_Reveal.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    label_Reveal.Text = "Your input is invalid!";
    label_Reveal.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num;
    bool guessCorrect = int.TryParse(textBox_Guess.Text, out num);
    if(!guessCorrect){
        label_Reveal.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        label_Reveal.Text = "Your input is invalid!";
        label_Reveal.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: tryparse will return an int as out parameter and int's and bool's aren't interchangable in c# as in C++ :) so this is a compile time exception

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `int.Parse()` instead for `int.TryParse()` then you will get exception:

> The **int.Parse** method is strict. With an invalid string, it throws a
>   FormatException. We can catch this using a try-catch construct.
>
> **But:** Using the int.TryParse method is usually a better solution. TryParse is faster,It's a method for parsing integers is the int.TryParse method. The parsing logic in TryParse is the same. But the way we call it is different.

If you are okey with `int.Parse()` then you can use the following,

```
try
{
   guess=int.Parse(textBox_Guess.Text);          
}
catch
{
    label_Reveal.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    label_Reveal.Text = "Your input is invalid!";    
    label_Reveal.Visible = true;      
}
```

Or else you should use `TryParse with if` as described below:

```
if(!int.TryParse(textBox_Guess.Text, out guess))
{
   label_Reveal.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
   label_Reveal.Text = "Your input is invalid!";    
   label_Reveal.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: What's the point in throwing and then catching an exception when you can handle the situation without the extra boilerplate with TryParse?

Comment: Using exceptions for program flow is a very bad idea. That's why the `TryParse` methods were added to the framework to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `int.TryParse`, use `int.Parse`, if you want to handle exception:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        guess = int.Parse(textBox_Guess.Text);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        label_Reveal.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        label_Reveal.Text = "Your input is invalid!";
        label_Reveal.Show();
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer `TryParse` then handle it within if statement like this:

```
if(!int.TryParse(textBox_Guess.Text, out guess))
{
    // manage parsing error here
}
```

Comment: Using exceptions for program flow is a very bad idea. That's why the `TryParse` methods were added to the framework to avoid this.

Comment: In ideal world - maybe. But not when .NET code itself violates this rule in too many scenarios.

Comment: That's true, but that doesn't stop it being a bad idea and it shouldn't be an excuse to do the wrong thing when you don't have to.