# input only numbers in the datatable WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I have a Datatable, how to make, so the user can enter only numbers in rows Datatable?

```
DataColumn column;
            DataRow row;

            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            column.ColumnName = "Типы";
            column.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: The same thing that you are looking for, but with a textbox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/463335/5147720

Comment: Are u using DataGrid ? Use DataGridTemplateColumn with a TextBox in CellTemplate. You can then listen to PreviewKeyPress event to reject alphabet keypress.

Comment: cscmh99 Thanks, you so i did

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
 myTable.Columns.Add("numericColumn", typeof(Int32)); // for integer column
 myTable.Columns.Add("CharColumn", typeof(char)); // for character column
 myTable.Columns.Add("DecimalColumn", typeof(Decimal)); // for Decimal column
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in line with the numbers, you can still enter characters