# C# Call KeyEvent inside an Event

Tags: c#, events, keyevent

I'd like to call a KeyEvent from within an Event. Something like...

```
private void txtPostcode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TxtboxNumbersOnly(sender, e);
    }
```

Where TxtboxNumbersOnly is a KeyEvent.
However it isn't allowed. I've also tried casting but it is giving an error. What would be the correct way of doing this?

---

Thanks, Grant. A snippet follows..

```
private void TxtboxNumbersOnly(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //Allow arrow keys
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Up:
        case Keys.Down:
        case Keys.Left:
        case Keys.Right:
        case Keys.PageUp:
        case Keys.PageDown:
        case Keys.Delete:
            e.SuppressKeyPress = false;
            return;
```

The error is:

> Argument2:cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs'.

Comment: Thanks, Grant.
A snippet follows..
`private void TxtboxNumbersOnly(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
        {
            //Allow arrow keys
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Up:
                case Keys.Down:
                case Keys.Left:
                case Keys.Right:
                case Keys.PageUp:
                case Keys.PageDown:
                case Keys.Delete:
                    e.SuppressKeyPress = false;
                    return;
` etc.
The error is Argument2:cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're handling the wrong event in the first place.

You can't just go and call `TxtboxNumbersOnly` because you don't have the `KeyEventArgs` to send it. And you can't convert `EventArgs` as, in this case, they are two different types.

You should be handling the `TextBox.KeyDown` event. The code should look like this:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.PageUp:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.Delete:
                e.SuppressKeyPress = false;
                return;
        }
    }
```

Having said that, I don't see what this code is doing...

Comment: I think I'm beginning to see the error in my ways. The full event code is

Comment: This is the right answer. The only way to get KeyEventArgs in the first place.

Comment: I'm showing my raw Overflow talents here (lack of). Unable to share the full code due to comment character limits. The full code prevents the user from typing non-number keys into the text box. I'm beginning to see the error in my ways, thank you. But still getting foiled by the code that gets added in Main.Designer.cs

Comment: @ionside - You need to just attach the `KeyDown` event from the text box properties.. If you do it by double-clicking the text box then you only get the `TextChanged` event.

Comment: @ionside - Perhaps you should look at this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/463335/259769.