# How can I make a TextBox accepts only numeric values?

Tags: c#

I would like to know if there is a proper way for a textbox to accept only numbers.

For example, I want it to "stop" the user from filling it with  "abcd1234" and only let him fill with "1234".

Comment: When you say you want the string to stop the user from entering non-numerical characters are you then talking about a TextBox ?  If not please add more information about this.

Comment: Yes Textbox, i update it now!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Comment: first, what technology are you using? MVC, webpages, WPF, UWP, etc...? On the second hand, I'm guessing you map that to a property, so you should set that property to an `int`, and third, you can set your input to `type=number`(this works for web, not sure for WPF, UWP and others) and that will only allow numbers to be entered.

Comment: Why don't you use a numericUpDown? Is better if you just want there to be numbers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I tried following code and worked fine for me. The `textbox` will allow user to enter *numbers only*.

```
private void txtbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) 
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

you can also try this

```
e.Handled = !(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar));
```

Comment: Can user paste non-numeric with that?

Comment: No, Even though user try to enter alhabetics also,it won't allow.

Comment: How i "call" the method txtbox1_KeyPress with my textbox in the main method?

Comment: Copy-paste .. Are you sure ?

Comment: To prevent copy/paste in TextBox using the keyboard set ShortcutsEnabled property to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate the input using the following lines of code:

```
if (txtNumericBox.Text.All(char.IsDigit))
   // Proceed
else
   // Show error
```

If you define this as a string property with getter and setter then you can use like the following:

```
private string _MyNemericStringr;

public string MyNemericString
{
    get { return _MyNemericStringr; }
    set {
        if (value.All(char.IsDigit))
            _MyNemericStringr = value;
        else
            _MyNemericStringr = "0";
    }
}
```

In the second example, if you assign any non-digit value to the property then it will return the value as `"0"`. otherwise it will process as usual.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this simple code.

```
private void keypressbarcode(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        e.Handled = !(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back);
}
```

it only accept **numeric** values and **Backspace**