# Limit user number input. WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't know if i'm going crazy or what but I've looked for hours and I can't find a way to limit user number input for a WinForm application for a minimum of .001 to a max of 1000. Could anyone show me the code for this?

```
private void Height_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
            (e.KeyChar != '.'))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numeric values.");
    }
    // only allow one decimal point
    if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You did took a look at [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers), didn't you?

Comment: Eh, `MaskedTextBox` with `000.000` mask?

Comment: Yes, I have taken a look there. Am I missing something?

Comment: `NumericUpdown` or `MaskedTextBox`

Comment: or combobox. You've been in this too long. Get some caffeine and chill for a few minutes.

Comment: And remember - you can always validate the old-fashioned way using if/then.