# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' after exiting the app

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

```
 if (int.Parse(q.textBoxNumberOfEmployees.Text) < 15)
        {
            Rect1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        }
```

scenario: main window and a child window, mainWindowButton opens the child window and the user enters information, when the user enters information the child window closes and in the main window a rectangle shows filled accordingly. Everything works!
But when i click on the child window's "x" to close the window manually it shows me this error, only then! I looked for an answer in previous questions similar to mine, but none have the exact problem.

All the code is in the MainWindowButton_ClickEvent

Comment: A guess based only on what you have above - the first suspect would be `int.Parse` where the (assumed) user entry isn't parseable as an `int`. Look into `int.TryParse`. Hth

Comment: Yes, this is going in the right direction, since the user hasn't entered any number(info required) the computer cannot parse blank space. but how can i fix it and not change everything since there are 11 more if's like this one!

Comment: Try wrapping your if statement in a try/catch block. I'm betting when you're exiting out of your child window int.TryParse is trying to parse a null value, and integers cannot be null.

Comment: exactly that is the case, the problem is i'm still in the learning phase and dont know how to use try/catch block properly :S

Comment: @Newbie use TryParse, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the comment I made on your OP, I'll try to write it out for you, it's actually pretty simple to use:

```
    try
    {
        if (int.Parse(q.textBoxNumberOfEmployees.Text) < 15)
        {
            Rect1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        }
    }
    catch(System.FormatException ex) //This code will be executed because a System.FormatException was thrown
    {
        //write the error message to the console (optional)
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        //You can write whatever code you'd like here to try and combat the error.
        //One possible approach is to just fill Rect1 regardless. Delete the
        //code below if you would not like the exception to fill Rect1
        //if this exception is thrown.

        Rect1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
    }
```

Comment: i still get the error even with the try/catch in this example, it says that the input string is in bad format. 
I just want to user to be able to close the window manually without entering any information. Maybe i should mention that in the error center it says something about DateTime

Comment: "when converting a string to DateTime..."

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like the code that you posted in your original post isn't actually the problem. If the issue is converting a string to a DateTime, that has to be happening somewhere else in your code. Can you post that code?

Comment: but it places the breakpoint on that line of code giving the error. i have alot of code, dont know which one to share here :/

Comment: this try/catch block could actually work, I'll have to test it out on all of the rectangles i have, and I'll get back at you

Comment: yes, this is the soultion! thank you very much. i just added q.close() - close child window, instead of Message and rectangle fill

Answer (score 2):

It is possible the user does not enter an integer into `q.textBoxNumberOfEmployees` so you need to handle that.

**Approach 1**

```
var numOfEmployees;

if (!int.TryParse(q.textBoxNumberOfEmployees.Text, out numOfEmployees))
{
    // What do you want to do? The user did not enter an integer.
}

// Proceed normally because user entered integer and it is stored in numOfEmployees
```

**Approach 2**

Only allow the user to enter numbers into the textbox as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers) answer. Since you have that check in multiple places, I would create a user control for this so it allows only numbers. Then use that user control every where it is needed. It is up to you which approach you want to go with.

Comment: okay i tried this and in the if statement i typed in q.Close(); q being the child window, and the exception still pops up, maybe i should type in something else?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your question? what do you mean i typed in q.CLose()?

Comment: with this code you gave me in the if statement i used the close() method to close the child window, since that is all I want for the app to do if the user hits the "x" and closes the window without entering any information