# Compare two textbox in c#

Tags: c#

How can I compare two textboxes in c# using greater than or less than. Im working on billing system. I want the cash shoould be bigger than the total. if not. it will pop up messagebox for error. I already try convert to int. to double. to string.
Here's my current code right now.

```
if (txtCash.TextLength < txtTotal.TextLength){
    MessageBox.Show("Cash must me bigger than the        total");
    txtCash.Focus();
    return;
  }
```

Any one can help me how? 
I know text length is wrong. but im just using it.

Comment: Post the code please

Comment: even though we can do it, you first have to provide what you have tried.

Comment: Il already add my code :) sorry.

Comment: If you only want to accept numbers use a numericbox

Comment: how? can give some example?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on billing system. I want the cash should be bigger than
>   the total. if not. it will pop up message box for error.

You might be looking for something like this:

```
if (double.Parse(txtCash.TextLength) <= double.Parse(txtTotal.TextLength))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cash must me bigger than the total");
    txtCash.Focus();
    return; // i dont know why you put this here but i'll leave it there anyway.
}
else
{
    var amount = double.Parse(txtCash.TextLength);
    // DO something
}
```

You may want to further validate the user input if you wish. Example, if the user doesn't enter numbers...

---

Better ways to achieve your task in the most robust way possible, you should consider the below links:

[How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

[double.TryParse(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Update:**

Seems, you're not sure about the keyword [var](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx). I suggest you have a deep read of the MSDN reference page for [var](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).

Comment: What's the use of var amount? hehe

Comment: Didnt work :/ it says double.Parse(String) has some invalid arguments. btw, I already get the idea in else. hehe

Comment: that's explanatory. I have also attached few links to help you out further.