# ^[0-9]+$ is allowing white spaces in my asp.net web application, any patterns to correct it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a text box and I need to allow only numbers,using ^[0-9]$ will not work perfectly, if we enter only white spaces, page.is valid becomes true
how is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Comment: @Istanfin - a winforms question is unlikely to produce a good answer for an [tag:asp.net] question

Comment: [RegularExpressionValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks): "Validation succeeds if the input control is empty. If a value is required for the associated input control, use a RequiredFieldValidator control in addition to the RegularExpressionValidator control."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can specify the pattern correctly as

```
ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"
```

- ^ Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- [0-9]* Matches zero
- or more characters $ Anchors the regex at the end of the string.

Comment: True, but it doesn't answer the question: why does validation succeed for a whitespace-only (or empty) textbox?