# C# KeyChar error

Tags: c#, eventargs

Hello everyone i made C# program and i want to make textbox only accept Number i tryed many different code and i get same errors please help 
this is my code

```
    private void agetxt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

and this is the error message i get

Error   CS1061  'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'KeyChar' and no extension method 'KeyChar' accepting a first argument of type 'EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   WindowsFormsApplication1    C:\Users\ziadm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form2.cs 176 Active

Comment: variable e is of type EventArgs, the class EventArgs does not have a public variable KeyChar. did you want to call a function like getKeyChar() ? or maybe the variable KeyChar in EventArgs is not public.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Answer (score 4):

You're using a `Click` event which **doesn't** contain the `KeyChar` property. You'd probably like to use the `KeyPress` event on the `TextBox` and implement the same logic which incorporates the `KeyChar` property to be able to check if the typed character is a digit or not.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        agetxt.KeyPress += agetxt_KeyPress;
    }


    private void agetxt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure this is going to work, why should this not cause the same error?

Comment: When you use the `KeyPress` event it uses KeyPressEventArgs which contains the `KeyChar` property. `EventArgs` doesn't contain the `KeyChar` property. I tried my code out and it only allows numbers.

Comment: i didn't notice you changes EventArgs e to KeyPressEventArgs e, my bad, this will work.

Comment: Note that OP uses a `Click` event and I use the `KeyPress` event.

Comment: i changed it to the Keypress From the event Thanks again @DonatPants

Comment: @AndrewMorton Updated answer!

Comment: Don't suggest keypress events for input validation. Users can still paste text containing non-numeric characters using the context menu, but not navigate through text anymore using arrow keys, Delete or Backspace using this approach. This answer maybe fixes the compiler error, but the underlying problem of the OP is not solved by this.

Comment: @CodeCaster For all we know, the OP posted an MVCE and has other code to handle paste. Otherwise, they're going to go through a learning process.

Comment: @Andrew the approach is broken by design. Like I said, you can fix the compiler errors, but then it's still broken. Again: this code prevents the use of Backspace, but still allows non-numerical characters to be pasted into the textbox. It is not a good answer.