# Input string was not in a correct format, Textbox from another Form

Tags: c#, .net, forms, parsing, textbox

This might be a duplicate but i haven't found anyone with the exact same issue as me so thats why i made a post. 
I get the 'Input string was not in a correct format' error when ever i try to convert textbox text to int.
To get the text from input textbox:

```
public void textBoxValue1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBoxValue1Text = sender as TextBox;
        string textBoxValue1ConvertedText = 
        System.Convert.ToString(textBoxValue1Text);
        value1txt = textBoxValue1ConvertedText;
    }
```

And to convert it:

```
string search1value = FormParameters.value1txt;
int search1ValueInt = int.Parse(FormParameters.value1txt); // Error occurs here
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the contet of `FormParameters.value1txt` when you debug? Not an int I guess.

Comment: Ive only allowed numbers to be entered in the textbox, so ive enter for example "1" and I get "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 1".

Comment: What is the value of `search1value` during runtime?

Comment: Before giving it a value its 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this method

```
public void textBoxValue1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBoxValue1Text = sender as TextBox;
    string textBoxValue1ConvertedText = System.Convert.ToString(textBoxValue1Text);
    value1txt = textBoxValue1ConvertedText;
}
```

`textBoxValue1Text` is not the text of the `TextBox`; it is the `Textbox` itself.

Use

```
string textBoxValue1ConvertedText = System.Convert.ToString(textBoxValue1Text.Text);
```

instead.

When you convert the `TextBox` to string you're calling the `.ToString()` of the `TextBox` and not the value of the `Text` property.

Comment: Wow i feel stupid now, thanks for the help mate it works now.