# Checking if a number is integer before comparing them not working in vb net

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb net and I was trying to create a program that checks 2 text box inputs:

I have experience in MS Access vba where we can force input box to only accept numbers. But I found out that this was not possible in VB.net. So I did some research for integer cheking and came up with this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.txtTeam1.Text = 0
        Me.txtTeam2.Text = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtTeam1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtTeam1.TextChanged
        If checkType(Me.txtTeam1.Text) = True Then
            changeBackColor()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invlaid Entry", "Please Enter a number")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtTeam2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtTeam2.TextChanged
        If checkType(Me.txtTeam2.Text) = True Then
            changeBackColor()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invlaid Entry", "Please Enter a number")
        End If
    End Sub

    Function changeBackColor()
        Try
            If Convert.ToInt32(Me.txtTeam1.Text) < Convert.ToInt32(Me.txtTeam2.Text) Then
                Me.txtTeam1.BackColor = Color.Gray
                Me.txtTeam2.BackColor = Color.Green
            ElseIf CInt(Me.txtTeam1.Text) > CInt(Me.txtTeam2.Text) Then
                Me.txtTeam1.BackColor = Color.Green
                Me.txtTeam2.BackColor = Color.Gray
            Else
                'Both are equal
                Me.txtTeam1.BackColor = Color.Gray
                Me.txtTeam2.BackColor = Color.Gray
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Invlaid Entry", "Please Enter a number")
        End Try

    End Function

    Function checkType(num As String) As Boolean
        Try
            Convert.ToInt32(num)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

However, as soon as the form loads I get the invalid entry message box even though the default value is 0. Even when I enter a valid number in either of the text box I get the invalid input message

Comment: In `TextChanged`, verify whether the Text is null or empty before calling `checkType()` (`if string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTeam1) then return`). You should use `Integer.TryParse()`, not a Try/Catch block. You can also create a Custom Control, derived from TextBox, override CreateParams and add  [ES_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-control-styles) to the Styles: the TextBox will only accept numbers and will also give visual clues that the input is wrong, using the standard *feedback* of the ErrorProvider class.

Comment: You will be well served by using [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) to get Visual Studio to tell you where variable types don't match up. Set it as the default for new projects, and set it for this current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method [`Integer.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) to check if a string can be parsed as an integer, and it doesn't throw an exception if it can't, it just returns True if it could parse the string into a number and puts the value in the second parameter, otherwise it returns False and sets the second parameter to 0 (actually it uses the default value of the type of the variable of the second parameter).

If you don't want the boxes to be changing colour as the user types, you can use the Validating event instead of the TextChanged event.

Furthermore, you can control when the event handler is applied by deleting the `Handles ...` part and manually adding it with the command [`AddHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement). That would prevent it from complaining at the moment you have set `txtTeam1.Text = "0"` but before setting the other textbox. You can even use just one event handler to handle more than one event, like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Sub ChangeBackColors()
        Dim team1 = 0
        Dim team2 = 0

        If Integer.TryParse(txtTeam1.Text, team1) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(txtTeam2.Text, team2) Then

            If team1 < team2 Then
                Me.txtTeam1.BackColor = Color.Gray
                Me.txtTeam2.BackColor = Color.Green
            ElseIf team1 > team2 Then
                Me.txtTeam1.BackColor = Color.Green
                Me.txtTeam2.BackColor = Color.Gray
            Else
                'Both are equal
                Me.txtTeam1.BackColor = Color.Gray
                Me.txtTeam2.BackColor = Color.Gray
            End If

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry", "Please enter a whole number.")

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtTeam_Validating(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ChangeBackColors()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtTeam1.Text = "0"
        txtTeam2.Text = "0"

        AddHandler txtTeam1.Validating, AddressOf txtTeam_Validating
        AddHandler txtTeam2.Validating, AddressOf txtTeam_Validating

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "[^0-9]") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.")
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(TextBox1.Text.Length - 1)
    End If
    End Sub
```

If you want to know more you can take a look at this.
[How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)