# Prevent users entering alphabetical characters but allow numerical and symbols

Tags: c#, forms

I've got a combo box that I want to allow users to enter in numerical digits, but not allow them to enter alphabetical characters.

My problem is that these numbers can be decimal so I need to allow the user to enter `.`

I've used `char.IsSymbol` but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to do.

```
private void DaySelection_ComboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a textbox that only accepts numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463299/how-do-i-make-a-textbox-that-only-accepts-numbers)

Comment: @madmonk46 it does under the surface but my question isn't just about accepting only numbers which is the confusion I had with the title of that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might be to have a specific list of allowed characters, and check against that. You can use a string for this for ease:

```
static readonly string _allowedNumericCharacters = "-0123456789.";

private void DaySelection_ComboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_allowedNumericCharacters.Contains(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Do you need the thousands separator? If so, you'll need to add `,` to the string.

Note that you might need to adjust that string for different locales. The decimal mark and the thousands separator is different for different locales.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use regex to do this, just something simple like

```
^[0-9.-]*$
```

This will just allow you to input any character between 0 and 9, a dot or a hyphen, then you just need to check if your string matches this. This should give the same result as the above answer.

Also I believe its better to test the whole string rather than an individual character upon a key press, this just adds extra protection for stuff like if they copy/paste text into the form