# How to block numerical input from user into textbox c#

Tags: c#

I am already blocking empty input now and I need to block numerical input for my textbox but I do not know how to do this

Here is my partial code

```
if (AmateurCheckBox.IsChecked == true)

        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(NewNameTextBox.Text))
            {
                Prompt();
            }


            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Amateur Competitor Added.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294611/input-handling-in-winform

Comment: This does not answer my question it is not a duplicate

Comment: There are answers there that allow you to formulate your own code to prevent users from entering numerical input using the Key events of a TextBox. The OP is asking for the same thing, "block certain input keys" to your "block numerical input".......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the `text` to `integer` value and see if parsing works; If parsing works, prompt for user input as per your logic.  However, I don't understand the second `else if` statement you had!!

```
if (AmateurCheckBox.IsChecked == true)

    {
        int outValue;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(NewNameTextBox.Text))
        {
            Prompt();
        }


        else if (Int.TryParse(NewNameTextBox.Text, outValue))
        {
            Prompt();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Amateur Competitor Added.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in event KeyPress of textbox :

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar);
}
```